# Select item in Django admin inline with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, django-admin, django-forms

Here's part of my models.py:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    birth_year = WideYear(null=True, blank=True)
    birth_year_uncertain = models.BooleanField()
    death_year = WideYear(null=True, blank=True)
    death_year_uncertain = models.BooleanField()
    flourit_year = WideYear(null=True, blank=True)
    flourit_year_uncertain = models.BooleanField()
    FLOURIT_CHOICES = (
        (u'D', u'Birth and death dates'),
        (u'F', u'Flourit date'),
    )
    use_flourit = models.CharField('Date(s) to use', max_length=2, choices=FLOURIT_CHOICES)
    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.personname_set.filter(default_name__exact=True):
            name = z(self.personname_set.filter(default_name__exact=True)[0])
        else:
            name = u'[Unnamed person]'
        if self.use_flourit == u'D':
            dates = '%s - %s' % (z(self.birth_year), z(self.death_year))
        else:
            dates = 'fl. %s' % (z(self.flourit_year))
        return '%s (%s)' % (name, dates)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['ordering_string']

class PersonName(models.Model):
    titles = models.CharField(max_length=65535, null=True, blank=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    middle_names = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    post_nominals = models.CharField(max_length=65535, null=True, blank=True)
    default_name = models.BooleanField()
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s, %s %s' % (self.surname, self.first_name, self.middle_names)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("titles", "surname", "first_name", "middle_names", "post_nominals", "person")
        unique_together = ("default_name", "person")
post_save.connect(post_save_person_and_person_name, sender=PersonName)
```

I want PersonName to be editable inline with Person in the admin as a TabularInline. Also, I want the default_name field of PersonName to display as a radio button, such that only one PersonName per Person can have default_name=True.

It's that last part that's the hard bit. Having a radio button interface within a form is relatively easy in Django. Having one that selects, essentially, one form in a formset, appears to be much, much harder.

One way to do this would be to add JavaScript to the change_form.html for Person that uses a regex to match the <input> elements for default_name and ensures that checking one of them unchecks the rest. But this seems as though it might become broken if Django's convention for naming HTML form fields changes; plus, it would only fix matters for users with JavaScript-enabled browsers.

Any better ideas gratefully received!

**UPDATE 17/9/2009**

The following admin template extension (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540851/jquery-change-element-type-from-hidden-to-input/560051#560051) and [this](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates)) implements the JavaScript suggestion above, but better solutions would be welcomed!

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

{% block extrahead %}
    <script src="/site_media/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            // Replace default_name checkboxes with radio buttons.
            $(".default_name input").each(function(){
                var name = $(this).attr('name'); // grab name of original
                var id = $(this).attr('id'); // grab id of original
                if ($(this).attr('checked')) { // grab checked value of original
                    var checked = ' checked="checked"';
                } else {
                    var checked = '';
                }
                /* create new visible input */
                var html = '<input type="radio" name="'+name+'" id="'+id+'" value="True"'+checked+' />';
                $(this).after(html).remove(); // add new, then remove original input
            });
            // Ensure only one default_name radio button can be checked at a time.
            $(".default_name input").click(function(){
                $(".default_name input").not(this).removeAttr("checked");
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you won't be getting a conventional HTML-only method of doing what you want.

You shouldn't have to rely on regex here though.  Can't you add a class name to your input fields so that jquery...

I guess that's harder than I first thought (answered here):
[Define css class in django Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401025/define-css-class-in-django-forms)

It's only a slightly better solution though.