# jQuery change input type

Tags: jquery, attributes

Trying to change `input` type attribute from `password` to `text`.

```
$('.form').find('input:password').attr({type:"text"});
```

Why this doesn't work?

Comment: Fyi, you can use `.attr('attrname', 'newvalue')` to set a single attribute.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/jquery-change-type-of-input-field

Comment: @thisgeek I'm genuinely impressed that you posted a duplicate link for a question more than two years old with a question from three years ago.

Comment: It does work now.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can't do this with jQuery, [it explicitly forbids it](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L284) because IE doesn't support it (check your console you'll see an error.

You have to remove the input and create a new one if that's what you're after, for example:

```
$('.form').find('input:password').each(function() {
   $("<input type='text' />").attr({ name: this.name, value: this.value }).insertBefore(this);
}).remove();
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/dHzzN/)

To be clear on the restriction, jQuery will not allow changing `type` on a `<button>` or `<input>` so the behavior is cross-browser consistent (since IE doens't allow it, they decided it's disallowed everywhere).  When trying you'll get this error in the console:

> **Error:** type property can't be changed

Comment: @Andy - Doesn't it get confusing with your body here and your head on meta? :)

Comment: @Nick, I'm too scared to edit your code, but I'm thinking you've got a typo: `.inserBefore(this)`

Comment: @ricebowl - You can edit away whenever you see an error, or post a more correct answer :) I appreciate the comment, fixed!

Comment: @Nick, yes :) it's especially difficult reading questions without a head.  Fortunately, there's always the jQuery braille plugin ;)

Comment: Oh, I wasn't scared of *you*, I was scared that you might know of an arcane, and mystical, jQuery function of which I was unaware and knew not the power of. I just didn't want to embarrass myself by wrongly stating that `inserBefore` didn't exist... =)

Comment: @WorkingHard - You're right the document fragment creation doesn't work there, seems it should...I'll file a bug with jQuery core later today, for now change it to use `.attr()` like the updated answer, I added a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/dHzzN/

Comment: A bit unfortunate that jQuery decided to block this ability for all browsers just because IE doesn't support it.

Comment: It's 2016 and jQuery allows to change attributes now.

Comment: $(element).attr('type', 'text');

Answer (score 58):

my solution:

```
    $('#myinput').clone().attr('type','tel').insertAfter('#myinput').prev().remove();
```

Comment: very elegant and simple :)

Comment: Nice solution, although as per the accepted answer, problematic if you have events attached to the original input, which are removed too...

Comment: How does `.attr()` work on the cloned element but not on the element itself?

Comment: Because the cloned element is not injected to the DOM yet, while the element itself is already in the DOM.

Comment: I think this should be the chosen answer!

Answer (score 22):

USE `prop` instead `attr`

```
$('.form').find('input:password').prop({type:"text"});
```

Answer (score 10):

I know I'm a little late to the game, but I was just able to do this in IE9 (it appears that Microsoft decided to allow it?). However, I had to do it with straight JavaScript. This is just a sample of a form with a dropdownlist that changes the field type depending on what is selected in the dropdown.

```
function switchSearchFieldType(toPassword) {
    $('#SearchFieldText').val('');
    if (toPassword === true) {
        $('#SearchFieldText').get(0).setAttribute('type', 'password');
    } else {
        $('#SearchFieldText').get(0).setAttribute('type', 'text');
    }
}

$('#SelectedDropDownValue').change(function () {
    if ($("select option:selected").val() === 'password') {
        switchSearchFieldType(true);
    }
    else {
        switchSearchFieldType(false);
    }
}).change();
```

Comment: I like this solution because not destroying the original inputs leaves any attached events intact...

Answer (score 9):

It's 2018 and jQuery does support this feature now. The following will work:

```
$('.form').find('input:password').attr("type","text");
```

Answer (score 7):

This should work easily.

```
$("selector").attr('type', 'hidden'); 
//Changing it to hidden
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Get current input object
    var oldInput = $('foo');
    //Clone a new input object from it
    var newInput = oldInput.clone();
    //Set the new object's type property
    newInput.prop('type','text');
    //Replace the old input object with the new one.
    oldInput.replaceWith(newInput);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are two functions, accepting an array of selector(s) as a parameter that will accomplish this:

```
  // Turn input into Number keyboard
  function inputNumber(numArr) {
    if (numArr instanceof Array) {
      for (var i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++) {
        if ($(numArr[i]).length > 0) {
          var copy = $(numArr[i]);
          var numEle = copy.clone();
          numEle.attr("type", "number");
          numEle.insertBefore(copy);
          copy.remove();
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // Turn input into Email keyboard 
  function inputEmail(emailArr) {
    if (emailArr instanceof Array) {
      for (var i = 0; i < emailArr.length; i++) {
        if ($(emailArr[i]).length > 0) {            
          var copy = $(emailArr[i]);
          var numEle = copy.clone();
          numEle.attr("type", "number");
          numEle.insertBefore(copy);
          copy.remove();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

You can then use this like:

```
  var numberArr = ["#some-input-id", "#another-input-id"];
  var emailArr = ["#some-input-id", "#another-input-id"];

  inputNumber(numberArr);
  inputEmail(emailArr);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function passShowHide(){
  if( $("#YourCheckBoxID").prop('checked') ){
    document.getElementById("EnterPass").attributes["type"].value = "text";
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("EnterPass").attributes["type"].value="password";}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.  The question is how to change the **type**, and this code changes the **value**, and it even does that poorly.  This *might* be a suitable answer for an entirely different question, but not for this question.

Answer (score -1):

This is pretty easy thou. This works pretty fine.

```
 $('#btn_showHide').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).text() == 'Show')
    {
      $(this).text('Hide');
      $('#code').attr('type', 'text');
    }
    else
    {
      $(this).text('Show');
      $('#code').attr('type', 'password');
    }
  });
```