# How to replace input[type=submit] to input[type=text] using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery change input type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541514/jquery-change-input-type)

How to replace input[type=submit] to input[type=text] using jQuery?

This way does't work:

```
$('input[type=submit]').removeAttr('type').attr('type','text');
```

Comment: Have you wrapped your code in ready handler?

Comment: Don't do this: It causes problems. Remove and recreate the element instead.

Comment: what do you mean? This sounds like a bad idea anyway. Why would you want to change a *submit button* into a text field? What sense does that make?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't change that property type (don't know why but that is what firebug logs), so the best thing you can do is to totally remove the input-element and insert a new input with the correct type.

Use jQuery with something like this:

```
$('input[type=submit]').after("<input type='text' />");
$('input[type=submit]').remove();
```

Comment: jQuery forbids changing it because IE won't let you do it (http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/09/bug-237-type-is-readonly-attribute-in.html) (and creating a workaround for this would be rather painful)

Comment: what do you use to check this restriction in Firebug. Which tab, section do you use to debug this problem?

Comment: I see it in the console tab. I've made a JsFidde to test this, and there you can see the log stating it : [jsFiddle firebug log error when changing type attribute](http://jsfiddle.net/fXR44/1/)