# how can i toggle a <p:password> field to text and password with a checkbox check uncheck

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using p:password tag for registration. I want to toggle the field to text when it is checked with check box, it change to password type mode when it is unchecked. How to solve the problem with primefaces component. I am using primefaces 3.0 and jsf 2.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

under the cover generates the `<input type="PASSWORD"/>` field (with other attribute name etc..)

So now if you need to show password have a check box like

```
<input type="checkbox" id="showPassword" onclick="showPassword()"/> Show password
```

in javascript

```
function showPassword(){
  var showPasswordCheckBox = document.getElementById("showPassword");
  if(showPasswordCheckBox.checked){
        document.getElementById("ID_FOR_YOUR_PASSWORD_FIELD").type="TEXT";
  }else{
      document.getElementById("ID_FOR_YOUR_PASSWORD_FIELD").type="PASSWORD";
  }
}
```

Comment: Its work in <h:inputText type="password"> this format. But i am using <p:password   value="#{ngoPojo.password}"  id="ngo_password" binding="#{password}" required="true" immediate="true" requiredMessage="Enter the password"> how to use this script in this mode

Comment: it sends HTML to the browser try checking source of the page

Comment: I am using Primefaces Lightbox popup window in my application. The problem i am facing is when i click the link to open the corresponding page, its too slow to display the page through light box. Its take more time to loading. How i can i solve it.

Comment: You shouldcreate a new question at stackoverflow

Comment: Don't forget that this code doesn't work in IE. If you want it to work in IE, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3541516/1057527).