# How can I use Angular to output dynamic form fields?

Tags: angularjs

I want to render a form, based on a dynamic field configuration:

```
$scope.fields = [
    { title: 'Label 1', type: 'text', value: 'value1'},
    { title: 'Label 2', type: 'textarea', value: 'value2'}
];
```

This should output something that behaves like:

```
<div>
    <label>{{field.title}}<br />
        <input type="text" ng-model="field.value"/>
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>{{field.title}}<br />
        <textarea ng-model="field.value" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
    </label>
</div>
```

The simple implementation would be to use `if` statements to render the templates for each field type. However, as Angular doesn't support `if` statements, I'm lead to the direction of directives. My problem is understanding how the data binding works. The [documentation for directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) is a bit dense and theoretical.

I've mocked up a bare bones example of what I try to do here: http://jsfiddle.net/gunnarlium/aj8G3/4/

The problem is that the form fields aren't bound to the model, so the $scope.fields in submit() isn't updated. I suspect the content of my directive function is quite wrong ... :)

Going forward, I need to also support other field types, like radio buttons, check boxes, selects, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: can't change input type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148456/angularjs-cant-change-input-type)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The first problem you are running into regardless of the directive you are trying to create is  using ng-repeat within a form with form elements. It can be tricky do to how ng-repeat creates a new scope.

[This directive creates new scope.](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat)

I recommend also instead of using element.html that you use [ngSwitch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch) instead in a partial template.

```
<div class="form-row" data-ng-switch on="field.type">
    <div data-ng-switch-when="text">
        {{ field.title }}: <input type="text" data-ng-model="field.value" />
    </div>
    <div data-ng-switch-when="textarea">
        {{ field.title }}: <textarea data-ng-model="field.value"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

This still leaves you with the problem of modifying form elements in child scope due to ng-repeat and for that I suggest using the ngChange method on each element to set the value when an item has changed. This is one of the few items that I don't think AngularJS handles very well at this time.

Comment: Actually, ngSwitch was exactly what I needed. No scope issues encountered :) (yet). I still don't quite understand directives, but that's a task for another day ..

Comment: @GunnarLium Were you able to solve this problem? I'm trying to implement a similar solution but got stuck because of the same exact issues.. Wondering if you can share your insights if/how you solved the problem

Answer (score 4):

You might consider [Metawidget](http://metawidget.org) for this. It uses JSON schema, but is otherwise very close to your use case. Complete sample:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://metawidget.org/js/3.5/metawidget-core.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://metawidget.org/js/3.5/metawidget-angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            angular.module( 'myApp', [ 'metawidget' ] )
                .controller( 'myController', function( $scope ) {

                    $scope.metawidgetConfig = {
                        inspector: function() {
                            return {
                                properties: {
                                    label1: {
                                        type: 'string'
                                    },
                                    label2: {
                                        type: 'string',
                                        large: true
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $scope.saveTo = {
                        label1: 'value1',
                        label2: 'value2'
                    }

                    $scope.save = function() {
                        console.log( $scope.saveTo );
                    }
                } );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="myController">
        <metawidget ng-model="saveTo" config="metawidgetConfig">
        </metawidget>
        <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `type` attribute can be changed when the element is out of DOM, so why not a small directive which removes it from DOM, changes it type and then add back to the same place?

The `$watch` is optional, as the objective can be change it dynamically once and not keep changing it.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.rangeType = 'range';
  $scope.newType = 'date'
});

app.directive('dynamicInput', function(){
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      link: linkFunction
    };
    
    function linkFunction($scope, $element, $attrs){
      
      if($attrs.watch){
        $scope.$watch(function(){ return $attrs.dynamicInput; }, function(newValue){
          changeType(newValue);
        })
      }
      else
        changeType($attrs.dynamicInput);
      
      
      function changeType(type){
        var prev = $element[0].previousSibling;
        var parent = $element.parent();
        $element.remove().attr('type', type);
        if(prev)
          angular.element(prev).after($element);
        else
          parent.append($element);
      }
    }
});
```

```css
span {
font-size: .7em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h2>Watching Type Change</h2>
    Enter Type: <input ng-model="newType" /><br/>
    Using Type (with siblings): <span>Before</span><input dynamic-input="{{newType}}" watch="true" /><span>After</span><Br>
    Using Type (without siblings): <div><input dynamic-input="{{newType}}" watch="true" /></div>
    
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <h2>Without Watch</h3>
    Checkbox: <input dynamic-input="checkbox" /><br />
    Password: <input dynamic-input="{{ 'password' }}" value="password"/><br />
    Radio: <input dynamic-input="radio"  /><br/>
    Range: <input dynamic-input="{{ rangeType }}" />
</div>
```

Tested in latest Chrome and IE11.