# AngularJs Dynamic Input Type

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a dynamic input fields based on a given model.
I want the `input` elements to have a dynamic `type` property, but when I do it I get the following exception:

> Error: type property can't be changed

I've read that IE  doesn't support change of the input type, and therefore angular disallowed it for cross-browser compatibility, but I am sure there is a walkaround in my case, when the input elements are loaded only once and don't change after the first load.

**The model:**

```
        details: {
            serverName: { type: 'text' },
            port: { type: 'number' },
            nickname: { type: 'text' },
            password: { type: 'password' },
            channel: { type: 'text' },
            channelPassword: { type: 'text' },
            autoBookmarkAdd: { type: 'checkbox' }
        }
```

**The html code:**

```
           <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="(index,detail) in communication.details">{{index}}:
                    <input type="{{detail.type}}" ng-model="detail.value" /></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Use ng-switch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296949/how-can-i-use-angular-to-output-dynamic-form-fields

Answer (score 2):

As Mark said, using `ng-switch` will allow me using dynamic input types.