# How to add input forms dynamically in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-sanitizing

I want to change the form inputs dynamically , and i have tried doing it using ng-bind-html , but only label is getting displayed , text box doesn't appears on the DOM. Here what has to be written inside ctrl.content depends upon the values  from the server.

Note

> type value will be coming from server , and it can be dynamic

HTML

```
<div ng-bind-html="ctrl.content">
```

Controller

```
function myCtrl(type) {
   var ctrl = this;

   switch (type) {
     case 1:
      ctrl.content = " <div> Input : <input type=\"text\" > </div> ";
       break;
       case 2:
        ctrl.content = " <div> Input : <input type=\"textarea\" > </div> ";
         break;
     default:


   }
```

Dom Element :

```
<div class="padding ng-binding ng-scope" ng-bind-html="addMeassurments.content"> <div> Input :  </div> </div>
```

Comment: that looks jQueryish.. how about using ng-show/hide/if/switch instead?

Comment: the content to be displayed is dynamic, so i couldn't use ng-if/hide.

Comment: You're assigning your controller the value - shouldn't you assigning the $scope instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use Angular to output dynamic form fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296949/how-can-i-use-angular-to-output-dynamic-form-fields)

Comment: see my update ans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your assignment is all wrong

```
ctrl.content = " <div> Input : <input type=\"text\" > </div> ";
```

You should be assigning the markup to a $scope property. e.g.

```
$scope.content = " <div> Input : <input type=\"text\" > </div> ";
```

Secondly you should use the [$sce service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) to sanitize the html.  [Here's a plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/NDmEWxYQGMTjDuPCQwsq?p=preview) where this code demonstrates the intended behavior

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  var ctrl = this;
  $scope.click = function myCtrl(type) {
    switch (type) {
      case 1:
        $scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml("<div> Input : <input type=\"text\" > </div> ");
        break;
      case 2:
        $scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml(" <div> Input : <textarea></textarea> </div> ");
        break;
      default:
    }
  }
});
```

Note also that I changed your markup from **input type="textarea"** to a **textarea** element.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `$sce` service with `ngSanitize` module:

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize'])
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.html = function(){
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(`<div> Input : <input type=\"${$scope.type == 0 ? 'text' : 'textarea'}\" > </div>`);
    }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MyController" ng-init='type="0"'>
    text: <input type="radio" ng-model="type" value="0">
    textarea: <input type="radio" ng-model="type" value="1">
    <div ng-bind-html="html()"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

A `textarea` can not render `HTML` input type like `<input type=\"textarea\" >`..

and try with `$sce`.

```js
var app = angular.module('exApp',[]);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope,$sce){
$scope.text = $sce.trustAsHtml("<div> Input : <input type=\"text\" > </div> ");
$scope.textArea = $sce.trustAsHtml(" <div> Input : <textarea></textarea> </div> ");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="exApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
<div ng-bind-html="text"></div><br>
<div ng-bind-html="textArea"></div><br>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-if instead of ng-bind-html.

Something like this:

```
<div>
    <div ng-if="type===1">Input : <input type="text"></div>
    <div ng-if="type===2">Input : <input type="textarea"></div>
</div>
```

And in your controller, you will only need to *dynamically* assign type either 1 or 2 as value.