# Change input type using directives by checkbox click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

My main goal is to change the input type of a password to text by cliking a checkbox.

Understanding that DOM manipulations should be done in a directive and after reading [AngularJS: can't change input type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148456/angularjs-cant-change-input-type)

I stared my directive as follows ( All code included in  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcayne/K6Qgm/5/) )

```
 <div ng-app="SignComponents">
     <bca-sign-up-password> </bca-Sign-Up-Password>
 </div>
```

However I did not really make it work yet  . . . any suggestions? I am working it out in the angular way?

Thanks!

Comment: I just opened the fiddle. The variable scope is unknown (line 22). You may check that first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, `element.html` is a method not a property, so yo were overwriting the function inside of your `scope.$watch` callback.  Second, it's much easier on everyone (yourself, Angular, the browser) to just change the input type:

http://jsfiddle.net/K6Qgm/6/

```
scope.$watch('viewPasswordCheckbox', function (newValue) {
    element.find('input')[1].type = newValue ? 'password' : 'text';
});
```

Edit: If you really need to support older versions of IE (the above works in 9), you can render the input twice and show/hide it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/K6Qgm/7/

```
function (newValue) {
    var show = newValue ? 2 : 1,
        hide = newValue ? 1 : 2,
        elements = element.find('input');
    elements[hide].style.display = 'none';
    elements[show].style.display = '';
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `ng-hide` and `ng-show` is better then doing it manually, maybe something like this for the directive template:

```
<div>
  <input
    required
    type="text"
    name="password"
    class="input password"
    placeholder="Password"
    ng-hide="viewPassword"
    ng-model="user.Password"
  >
  <input
    required
    name="password"
    type="password"
    class="input password"
    placeholder="Password"
    ng-show="viewPassword"
    ng-model="user.Password"
  >
  <input type="checkbox" class="btn btn-mini" ng-click="showPassword()">
</div>
```

the linking function:

```
var linker = function(scope, element, attrs){
  scope.viewPassword = true;
  scope.showPassword = function(){
    scope.viewPassword = !scope.viewPassword;
  };
};
```

working example [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/quaUskeMRtMPSFoonbRw?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

How about creating 2 input field, One with input type=text and 2nd of input type=password pointing to same ng-model=user.password" and use checkbox (showpassword) to control which input is displayed.

```
<input ng-hide="showpassword" type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"   ng-model="user.password" />
<input ng-show="showpassword" type="text" name="password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.password" />
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="showpassword" ng-checked="false"> Show Password
```