# angular 1.4 directive toggle view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to show two different inputs depending on a toggle attribute.

No I have the problem that I should define each attribute/property of the input in my directive, but the binding doesn't work.

Directive:

```
angular.module('directive')
.directive('inputBlock', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            model: '=',
            modernStyle:'=',
            name:'=',
            type:'=',
            label:'='
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {},
        templateUrl: 'views/templates/inputBlockTemplate.html'
    };
});
```

Template:

```
<div>
<div ng-if="!modernStyle">
<label>{{label}}</label>
<input ng-model="model" name="{{name}}" type="{{type}}"/>
</div>
 <md-input-container ng-if="modernStyle">
  <label>{{label}}</label>
  <input ng-model="model" name="{{name}}" type="    {{type}}"/>
</md-input-container>
</div>
```

Usage:

```
 <input-block model="name" label="'firstname'" modern-style="true" name="'firstname'" type="'text'">
  </input-block>
```

Is it possible to do something like a toggle in directives? 
Furthermore is it possible to redirect the bindings to directives?

Comment: label, name, and type are HTML reserved attributes, I'm not sure you can bind some value to your directive trough them

Comment: That's right. i don't know if it is possible, but I also think that this will be a problem. 

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148456/angularjs-cant-change-input-type

one guy did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-if` creates a new child scope, try change by `ng-show/ng-hide`

### [Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#javascript-prototypal-inheritance)

**Other considerations:**

- As you use name,label and type as text inside your directive is not necesary that it will be binding, I recomend use `@` instead of `=`, or access it directly from the `attrs` link argument.
- The scope.model could be set as ngModel to use the default angular directive.

---

Javascript:

```
angular.module("directive").directive("inputBlock", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "AEC",
        replace: true,
        scope: {    
            ngModel: "=",
            modernStyle:"@",
            //name:"@",
            //type:"@",
            //label:"@"
        },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
         scope.type=attrs.type;
         scope.name=attrs.name;
         scope.label=attrs.label;
     },
    templateUrl: "views/templates/inputBlockTemplate.html"
    };
});
```

Template:

```
<div>
<div ng-show="!scope.modernStyle">
<label>{{scope.label}}</label>
<input ng-model="scope.model" name="{{scope.name}}" type="{{scope.type}}"/>
</div>
 <md-input-container ng-show="scope.modernStyle">
  <label>{{scope.label}}</label>
  <input ng-model="scope.model" name="{{scope.name}}" type={{scope.type}}"/>
</md-input-container>
</div>
```

Usage:

```
<input-block ng-model="name" label="firstname" modern-style="true" name="firstname" type="text">
  </input-block>
```

Comment: thank you, 
now i understood the difference between '=' and '@'.
It looks like my idea is possible to implement.