# Input type number inside angular directive produces string

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive:

```
<!-- directive -->
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {})
  .directive('test', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function(scope) {
        scope.value = 0;
        scope.type = 'number';
      },
      templateUrl: 'template.html'
    }
  });

<!-- template -->
<label>{{ type }}: <!--type == 'number' -->
  <!-- produces strings -->
  <input type="{{type}}" ng-model="value" class="form-control"  />
  <!-- produces integers -->
  <input type="number"  ng-model="value" class="form-control" />
</label>
<div>{{ value |json }}</div>


<!-- usage -->
<test />
```

The first imput box produces strings and the second integer. In my opinion, its a bug. Any thoughts or workarounds?

Here a plunker to reproduce it:
http://plnkr.co/edit/uLjYKxepzaaZIjGmObzi?p=preview

Greetings Lennart

Comment: did you try changing it via `element.type`?

Comment: yes, same problem.

Comment: I changed the code, to make it more clear, what happens

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily a bug but somewhat the intended behavior. It has to do with browser compatibility. [These answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148456/angularjs-cant-change-input-type) explains this in great detail.