# Replace an input with another dynamically created input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I want to replace an existing file input field entirely with a text input field, with all properties intact like `id`, `name`, etc. How do I do that using jQuery?

**Prelude**:

I have an `<input type="file" name=".." id=".." />` that I am using for AJAX based uploads. (yes, For IE, I am submitting the form using `IFRAME`s.)

When the upload is done, I go into my success callback function, where I am trying to change the original `<input type="file"` to `<input type="text"`.

In other browsers, this is working fine when I simply run the following code:

```
$originalInput[0].type = 'text';
$originalInput[0].value = 'response code';
```

But this is not working in IE, where I came to know from SO that it is a security concern and hence not allowed. I want to write minimum code for this.

Comment: how about removing the old input and inserting a new one?

Comment: How to do that with minimum code? Do I need to create an `input` in `jQuery` dynamically and iterate all properties of original input pushing them to new?

Answer (score 1):

From user2259571's answer, I did this following in a shorter one-line way:

```
$originalInput
    .replaceWith( $originalInput[0].outerHTML.replace(/type="file"/, 'type="input"') );
```

Answer (score 0):

Long live jQuery

```
    var fileInput = $('input[type="file"]');
    var textInput = $('<input type="text"/>');

    //can copy properties here 
    textInput.value = 'response code';
    textInput.className = fileInput.className;

textInput.insertBefore(fileInput);
textInput.remove();
```

Comment: How do I copy all the properties of previous file input into new text input?

Comment: you can use `attr` method or just by simple JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

IE does not allow this, but a workaround can be:

```
$('body').find('input:file').each(function() {
  $("<input type='text' />").attr({value: 'response code' }).insertBefore(this);
}).remove();
```

possible duplicate of [jQuery change input type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541514/jquery-change-input-type)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can reach this very simple by placing two inputs,

```
<input type="file" name="somename1" id="someid1"/>
<input type="text" name="somename1-after" id="someid1-after" style="display:none"/>
```

In you request callback you can remove the `type="file"` input field, strip the "-after"
suffix and show the `type="text"` input field.

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = $("input[type=file]");
var inputHTML = input.clone().wrapAll("<div>").parent().html();

var newinputHTML = inputHTML.replace(/type="file"/, 'type="text"');

input.replaceWith(newinputHTML);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QdZDb/1/

Comment: This is cool. I changed it to:
`input.replaceWith(input[0].outerHTML.replace(/type="file"/, 'type="input"'));`

Comment: outerHTML might not work on Firefox http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html