# Change <label> based on <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've had a dig through some similar questions (it's not a unique problem) but many only deal with the current label or changing the label to match the selection.

My jQuery skills are pretty average: the functions are fine, but chaining them (and knowing the browser tricks...) is a bit trickier.

What I'm aiming for is:

- User selects "Email" or "Web" from the `<select>` list.
- Based on this selection, we update the `<label>` of the `<input>` below and the content of the `<span>` below it (some help text, which will helpfully show "http://yourdomain.com/here" or "stuff@yourdomain.com")

Additionally:

- Change the `type` of the input field to/from `type="email"` or `type="url"`. From [what I can see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541514/jquery-change-input-type), this might be troublesome due to IE compatibility?
- The alternative may be to .show()/.hide() two inputs (one of each type) based on the selection instead.

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/ys9Cj/ (so far: I'm stuck at getting the fields to change. Like I said, not so great with JQuery!)

Here's the HTML:

```
    <label for="method">How?</label>
    <select id="method" name="method" required>
      <option name="method"  value="email">Email</option>
      <option name="method" value="web">Web</option>
    </select>
    <span class="help-text">The web, or email?</span>
  </label>

  <label for="contact">Email Address</label> // We want to update this (but not strictly with the value from the <select>
  <input type="email" name="contact" id="contact" value="" maxlength="255"> // and the type here, or otherwise .show() or .hide() this and show an alternative field with a different name=""
  <span class="help-text">e.g. stuff@yourdomain.com</span> // and change the contents here
```

Comment: share the jquery code u have used for the above scenario..

Comment: to make people answer ur question ,you have try and simplify your question..the first impression i get after just looking at the question is its too long to go through..shorter and precise the question..better response u will get..

Comment: @Onaseriousnote your display name made me smile :)

Comment: Try to create a JSFiddle, it will much easiler to understand, show what you tried and get a answer

Comment: I've added a (partial!) JSFiddle. @Onaseriousnote - I've tried to be specific here, as I have a few requirements. Saves me having to ask a chain of questions! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one mate http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/Pn8HZ/

Text change according to your selection, easy to manage via data attr

```
$("#method").change(function() {
    $('#help-text').text($('option:selected').attr('data-content'));
    $('#example-text').text($('option:selected').attr('data-example'));
}).change();
```

Comment: Cheers. I've just added `data-label` and `data-help-text` to the inputs, so I can populate <label> and #help-text with those strings when I show/hide them.

Answer (score 1):

There were few syntax errors in your HTML and JavaScript code. Please try below:

HTML:

```
<p>
<label for="method">How?</label>
<select id="method" name="method" required>
    <option value="email">Email</option>
    <option value="web">Web</option>
</select> <span class="help-text">The web, or email?</span>
</p>
<p>
<label id="contact-label" for="contact">Email Address</label>
<input type="email" name="contact" id="contact" value="" maxlength="255"> <span class="help-text">e.g. stuff@yourdomain.com</span>
    </p>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#method').change(
        function () {
            var method = $('option:selected', this).text();
            if (method == "Email") {
                $('#contact-label').text("Email Address");
            } else if (method == "Web") {
                $('#contact-label').html("App URL");
            }
        });
 });
```

Comment: This helped a lot: thanks very much. I've managed to figure out the rest (setting `required`, showing/hiding the other input on change), etc. The only issue is getting this to trigger not *just* on change, but also ensure it works on page load (when my template logic adds `selected`)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ys9Cj/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#method').change(
    function () {
        var method = $('option:selected').val();

        if (this.value == "email") {
            $('#contact').text("Email Address");
        } else if (this.value == "web") {
            $('#contact').text("Web Address");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: I suggest using data attributes to store the alternate text, storing it in Javascript isn't optimal. Other than that it's good!

Comment: @qwerty Can you expand on this? I assume you mean `data-help-text` - in which case, how can I leverage this to pull the help text in? Ideally I'd set this on the input and replace the content of `#contact-help-text` when I show/hide the respective inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Check this fidle

```
        $(document).ready(

    $('#method').bind('change',
      function(){
      var method = $('option:selected',this).text();
      alert(method);
      if (method == "Email") {
          $('#contact-label').text("Email Address"); 
     $('#help-change').text("Email Address"); 
          $('#contact').attr('type','email');

      } else if (method == "Web") {
          $('#contact-label').text("App URL"); 
          $('#help-change').text("Web Address"); 
          $('#contact').attr('type','url');
      }

      }
      )

  );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ys9Cj/18/

Comment: Thanks: it looks like I can't use `.attr('type','xxx')` for IE 8 and older: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score -2):

```
$("#method").change(function () {
    $('#contact').html(($(this).find(':selected').html() == 'Email' ? 'Email Address' : 'Web Address') + ':');       
});
```

Comment: please add an explanation to your answer