# ActiveAdmin allow users to set per_page value in index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, pagination, settings, activeadmin

The ActiveAdmin docs [explain](http://activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages.html) how to disable pagination and set the number of records per page in a Resource index using `config.per_page`, but I'm wondering if there is a built-in way to allow users to set the `per_page` value themselves, e.g. with a drop-down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such possibility.
You can only either set it as default globally

```
config.default_per_page = 50 #in config/initializers/active_admin.rb
```

or set it per resource by using `config.per_page` as you've already mentioned.

To enable a dropdown per_page setup config/initializers/active_admin.rb:
   config.default_per_page = [25,50,100]
or just in a resource 
    config.per_page = [25,50,100]

Answer (score 8):

It's certainly possible using:

```
ActiveAdmin.register MyModel do

  before_action only: :index do
    unless params[:per_page]
      # Default pagination option if it's not already set.
      @per_page = 30
    end
  end

  # The page drop down options.
  config.per_page = [10, 20, 30, 50, 75, 100]

  # .. rest of your activeadmin code.

end
```

Comment: I found no need for the before action.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a couple years old, but if I came across it, someone else might and I *finally* found a way to accomplish this using some pretty straight forward javascript!!

My Setup:

> Rails 4.2 with ActiveAdmin (1.0.0pre)

Background:

> - ActiveAdmin does interpret the `per_page` query string parameter (if passed in)
> - ActiveAdmin uses a hidden field `#hidden_active_admin_per_page` field
>     (in the filter section of the index page) to maintain this setting across additional filtering/paging (i.e. when this setting is changed, it sends the new value as a query string parameter with the other filter criteria)

I decided to leverage this built in functionality and simply expose this "hidden" field and make it visible to the admin (as a dropdown).

**Code I used**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var per_page_qty = $("#hidden_active_admin_per_page").val();

  $("#hidden_active_admin_per_page").remove();

  $("form.filter_form").prepend('
    <div class="select input optional filter_form_field filter_select" id="per_page_input">
      <label for="per_page" class="label">Results Per Page</label>
      <select name="per_page" id="hidden_active_admin_per_page">
        <option selected="selected" value="25">25</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
        <option value="500">500</option>
        <option value="1000">1000</option>
      </select>
    </div>');

  if (typeof per_page_qty !== 'undefined') {
    $("#hidden_active_admin_per_page").val(per_page_qty);
  }
});
```

**How it works**

1. Grab the per_page value from the hidden field which ActiveAdmin is using to manage per_page setting on the client side

   `var per_page_qty = $("#hidden_active_admin_per_page").val();`
2. Remove the hidden field added by active admin (because we [cannot simply unhide the hidden field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541514/jquery-change-input-type) and you requested a dropdown :))

   `$("#hidden_active_admin_per_page").remove();`
3. Add a "visible" input back to the filter section of the form

   `$("form.filter_form").prepend(...`
4. Set per_page input to value retrieved before removal of field

   `$("#hidden_active_admin_per_page").val(per_page_qty);`

**Additional Thoughts**

I hard coded the default per_page in the "pre-pended" input (i.e. `select`) to 25 because that was my default in my config.  You could most likely inject this value from rails default setting.