# jQuery change input type

Tags: jquery, text, input, passwords

This code doesn't work what's wrong?

```
$(".re").focus(function() {
    if($(this).attr("type") == "text") {
        $(this).attr("type", "password");
    }
});
```

It's supposed to change the input text type from text, to password, but doesn't work when I type in it after I get into focus on it; it's still text.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/jquery-change-type-of-input-field

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IE won't allow you to do this, so jQuery [specifically forbids it](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L291) to be cross-browser consistent.  To change the `type` (and it work in every browser) you need to replace the element with one of the other type.

Answer (score 6):

As Nick said you can't do this, but what you can do is have two inputs right next to eachother, with the password hidden. On focus, toggle each and `.focus()` the password.

### jQuery

```
$('.text').focus(function() {
    $(this).toggle();
    $('.pass').toggle().focus();
});​
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/KUFZY/