# input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox'); IE bug

Tags: javascript, html, input, checkbox

This problem shows only in ie.all other browser namely ff,chrome,safari,opera works well.
It doesn't show chcekbox instead shows a value box...

code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
 <style>
 *{margin:0;padding:0;}
 ul {
    padding:10px 10px 0 35px;
    list-style:none;
    }

 li{
 display:inline;
 text-weight:bold;
 color:#475D7F;
 }
 li img{margin-bottom:-2%;}
 </style>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--

function DOM(obj,id){
var total=10;
var coll=3;
var row=total/coll;

var tar=document.getElementById(id);
var table=document.createElement('TABLE');
  table.border='0';
  tar.appendChild(table);
var tbdy=document.createElement('TBODY');
  table.appendChild(tbdy);

  for (var zx1=0;zx1<=row;zx1++){
   var tr=document.createElement('TR');
   tbdy.appendChild(tr);
   for (var zx2=0;zx2<coll;zx2++){
    var td=document.createElement('TD');
    var ul=document.createElement('UL');    
    var input=document.createElement('INPUT');
    var img=document.createElement('IMG');

    tr.appendChild(td);
    td.width='200';
    td.appendChild(ul);
    var li1=document.createElement('LI');
    li1.appendChild(input);
    ul.appendChild(li1);
    input.setAttribute("name", "friend");
    ***input.setAttribute('Type', 'checkbox');***
    input.setAttribute("value", "yap frnd");
    input.setAttribute("id", "xyz");


    var li2=document.createElement('LI');
    ul.appendChild(li2);
    li2.appendChild(img);
    img.setAttribute("src", "x.jpg");
    img.setAttribute("title", "x");
    img.setAttribute("alt", "x");
    img.setAttribute("style", "padding-bottom:-2%;");

    var li3=document.createElement('LI');
    ul.appendChild(li3);      
    li3.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Ataus Samad Rubel'));

   }
  } 

}
//-->
</script>
</head>

<body>
<select onchange="DOM(this,'target');" >
<option >DOM Method</option>
<option >do</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

wish someone look into it..thanks for your appreciation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't change the `type` attribute of an `<input>` or `<button>` after adding it to the DOM in IE, so change it *before* appending it, like this:

```
input.setAttribute("name", "friend");
input.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
input.setAttribute("value", "yap frnd");
input.setAttribute("id", "xyz");
li1.appendChild(input);                 //this needs to happen after
```

Comment: perfect...thanks Nick & Darin.►li1.appendChild(input);◄►input.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");◄[lower case 't'] are what make it perfect.Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
                    ^
```

Notice the lowercase `t`.

Answer (score 1):

Since [IE doesn't support a change in an input type once it has been assigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/jquery-change-type-of-input-field), you should assign the type before adding it to the DOM.