# Simple Javascript does not work on Interner Explorer

Tags: javascript

I have a secure login form for my website. In the login process, I use a file called `form.js`. When I enter the username and the password, it loads but doesn't direct me to the page, however everything works fine on Chrome. I get this notification (click on the link for the image):

[image]

And this is the forms.js code:

```
function formhash(form, password) {
    // Create a new element input, this will be our hashed password field. 
    var p = document.createElement("input");

    // Add the new element to our form. 
    form.appendChild(p);
    p.name = "p";
    p.type = "hidden";
    p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);

    // Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent. 
    password.value = "";

    // Finally submit the form. 
    form.submit();
}
```

Any idea about this problem?

Comment: `hex_sha512`? That doesn't look like native JS to me.

Comment: Use `setAttribute()` to set the attributes, and do this before you add the node to your DOM. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3793615/1679849

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internet Explorer won't let you change an element's `type` attribute after it has been added to the DOM. You have to set this attribute *before* you append the node.

Also, the correct way of setting a node's attributes is by using the `setAttribute()` function.

This should work:

```
function formhash(form, password) {
    // Create a new element input, this will be our hashed password field. 
    var p = document.createElement("input");
    p.setAttribute("name","p");
    p.setAttribute("type","hidden");
    p.setAttribute("value",hex_sha512(password.value));

    // Add the new element to our form. 
    form.appendChild(p);

    // Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent. 
    password.value = "";

    // Finally submit the form. 
    form.submit();
}
```