# Set default value of a password input so it can be read

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to have a password field which says "Password" in it before a user enters their password (so they know what the field is)

I'd rather just use Javascript, importing jQuery for this alone seems wasteful, but I have no idea how to. The images explain quite clearly:

*What it looks like:*

[image]

*What I want it to look like:*

[image]

It's only a very simple website and the most basic of logins (has no validation etc)

Any ideas?

```
<input id="username" name="username" class="input_text" type="text" value="Username"  />
<input id="password" name="password" class="input_text" type="password" value="Password" />
```

Comment: You might be able to hack it by changing the type of the field dynamically (ie. first "text", change to "password" on activation). I'm not 100% sure this will work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change your `password` input to be a simple input type `text`. Then, with JavaScript (or JQuery) on focus event, change it to be a input type `password`.

Here is a little untested sample with plain JavaScript (no JQUERY):

```
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function makeItPassword()
      {
         document.getElementById("passcontainer")
            .innerHTML = "<input id=\"password\" name=\"password\" type=\"password\"/>";
         document.getElementById("password").focus();
      }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <form>
      <span id="passcontainer">
         <input onfocus="return makeItPassword()" name="password" type="text" value="Type Password" />
      </span>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1. That's how I would do it. `$("#password").bind("focus", function () { $(this).val(""); $(this).attr("type", "password"); });`

Comment: Note that changing the `type` of `input` elements is will not work properly on IE. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/

Comment: @CMS: Do you think the same thing applies if you create a new DOM element instead of changing an existing one? (look at my code sample).

Comment: Sadly this breaks the iPhone keyword :s

Comment: In 2018, you should use the `placeholder` attribute, which has [good browser support now](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder), instead of this hack.

Answer (score 18):

If you're using HTML5 then you should use the [placeholder attribute](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-placeholder-attribute).

```
<input id="username" name="username" class="input_text" type="text" placeholder="Username"  />
<input id="password" name="password" class="input_text" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
```

---

If you're using HTML4 you can create a [fake password field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/jquery-change-type-of-input-field/2304369#2304369).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pwdFocus() {
        $('#fakepassword').hide();
        $('#password').show();
        $('#password').focus();
    }

    function pwdBlur() {
        if ($('#password').attr('value') == '') {
            $('#password').hide();
            $('#fakepassword').show();
        }
    }
</script>

<input id="username" name="username" class="input_text" type="text" v="Username"  />
<input id="fakepassword" name="fakepassword" type="text" value="Password" style="color:#ccc" onfocus="pwdFocus()" />
<input id="password" name="password" class="input_text" type="password" style="display:none" onblur="pwdBlur()" />
```

Answer (score 6):

A simple solution:

```
<input id="username" name="username" class="input_text" type="text" placeholder="Username"  />
<input id="password" name="password" class="input_text" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to your javascript:

```
function makePasswordHidden() {
    document.getElementById("password").setAttribute("type", "password");
}
```

Change the input for the password to:

```
<input id="password" name="password" class="input_text" type="text" value="Password" onfocus="makePasswordHidden();">
```

What this does it it makes the input element a 'password' and the value is updated so that it is hidden. If you would like for the value="Password" to be visible if the field is left empty then add the following javascript function:

```
function makePasswordShown() {
    document.getElementById("password").setAttrivute("type", "text");
}
```

And add the following to your password input:

```
onblur="if (this.value=='') makePasswordShown(); if (this.value=='') this.value='Password';"
```

Answer (score -2):

I had another idea to deal with this problem and you will need no Javascript:

```
<input onclick="value=''; type='password';" name="password" type="text" value="Password" />
```

Or you can also do it like this:

```
<input onclick="this.value=''; this.type='password';" name="password" type="text" value="Password" />
```

I do not know the difference between this possibilities.
Another thing you could change is to write instead of `onclick=.......` `onfocus=.....`

I don't know the difference here, too.

But I hope I could help you. PS: Sorry because of my bad English I'm German.

Comment: "you will need no Javascript" - this _is_ JavaScript.