# html placeholder attribute in Firefox and IE for both text and password input

Tags: javascript, html

I found that does not work in IE and FF. I found some Javascript work arounds but the place holder text on the password would be stared out. I know this works the way it should in Chrome and i think Safari since they are both Webkit. Anyone have any idea or know of a working fix for IE and FF?

Answer (score 0):

Your only workaround would be placing a label on top of the text/password box and hiding it/showing the actual box when it's getting focus. For example, look at this jQuery [plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/defaultvalue) that will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [fake password field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/jquery-change-type-of-input-field/2304369#2304369).