# Changing Attribute "type" from text to password

Tags: jquery

Why isn't the jQuery changing the type attribute of #password_input to password?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#password_input").attr('type','password');
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="loginBox">
            <form>
            <input type="text" id="username_input" name="username" /><br />
            <input type="text" id="password_input" name="password" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

'type' property/attribute cannot be changed.

edit: This was accurate for JQuery at the time it was posted. See other answers for how it can be done now.

Comment: Look at bug reports on http://api.jquery.com/attr/ to see that you are not alone.  Firebug will even tell you that 'property cannot be changed'.

Comment: I'm not sure why this keeps getting voted down... Anyone care to explain why I keep getting downvotes?

Comment: because people are getting confused between jquery and javascript. maybe you can edit your answer to reflect that?

Comment: @candidJ Read the post. In 2011, JQuery did not have this ability.

Answer (score 25):

Yes, you can.

Try this

```
<input type="text" class="pwd">
  $('.pwd').click(function(){
  $(this).get(0).type='password';
});
```

Comment: Nice, but can this be accomplished without jQuery?

Comment: Btw, [is said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/jquery-change-type-of-input-field#comment15659291_1544338) that it does not work with IE7 and IE8. Anyway, worked in Chromium for me.

Comment: How does the get(0) part of this work? For me, it works on the page where intended, but causes bad side effects on other pages.

Comment: $(this).get(0) in this context is pointless. It makes a normal javascript object into a jquery object then gets the normal object straight back out. Just use this.type='password' instead.

Answer (score 7):

This is a security measure that most major browsers employ to mitigate screen-reading and password theft (it's more important going the other way, from `password` to `text`).

I can't tell from your code what you're trying to do, but here's my guess: you want a textbox with the word `Password` in it as a hint, and when it gets focus, the user enters their password as a password field. To accomplish this, you can use two elements: an `<input type="text">` and an `<input type="password">`, the latter hidden initially. When the user focuses on the textbox, simply hide it, show the password field, and set the focus. It could get tricky toggling back and forth between them.

#### Update

This is now way easier to accomplish in modern browsers. Simply use something like this (here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JimmySawczuk/CBYss/)):

```
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
```

Comment: yes thats exactly what I'm going for... but this threw a wench it what I thought would be fairly simple

Comment: @AndrewFerrara check my updated answer for focus blur solution

Answer (score 5):

You can always use the pure js like:

```
document.getElementsByName("login_pass")[0].type="text";
```

Comment: it can! I do it all the time with Java Script.

Comment: because the question is about jquery and not javascript

Answer (score 4):

You can't change the type attribute.  you must create a new element and delete the old one like this:

```
var originalBtn = $("#password_input");
var newBtn = originalBtn.clone();

newBtn.attr("type", "password");
newBtn.insertBefore(originalBtn);
originalBtn.remove();
newBtn.attr("id", "password_input");
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using .prop?

```
$("#password_input").prop('type','password');
```

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: It worked for me (to change the type from `hidden` to `initial`). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This will do it

```
$('<input type="password" id="password_input" name="password" />').insertAfter('#password_input').prev().remove();
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/RyVU8/

**UPDATE**

If you want to show plain text in a password field and then make it a regular password field on focus you can do the following

```
$('#clear').focus(function() {
    $('#clear').hide();
    $('#password_input').show().focus();
});
$('#password_input').blur(function() {
    if ($('#password_input').val() == '') {
        $('#clear, #password_input').toggle();
    }
});
```

where `#clear` represents a text field that shows instead of the password field when it's in blur and user hasn't entered any password yet.

### check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/uNGKb/3/

Answer (score 1):

```
<span>Password:</span>
<input type="text" id="pwd" style="width: 180px; color: Gray;" onfocus="Changetxt();this.type='password'" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.type='text';textboxtype();}" value="Enter Your Password Here" />

 <script>

        function Changetxt() {
            if ($('#pwd').val() == "Enter Your Password Here") {
                $('#pwd').val('');
                $('#pwd').css('color', 'black');
            }
        }

        function textboxtype() {
            if ($('#pwd').val().length < 1) {
                $('#pwd').val('Enter Your Password Here');
                $('#pwd').css('color', 'gray');
            }
        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply create 2 sync Input fields. One as password and one as text.
Then switch their visiblity via button.
Don't forget to hide the text-input on start.

```
<input type="password" id="inp_passwd"/><input type="password" id="inp_passwd2"/>
<input id="btn_show_passwd" type="button" value="Show Password" />
```

Javascript:

```
// sync input fields
$('#inp_passwd').keyup(function(){
    $('#inp_passwd2').val($(this).val());
});
// show clear password
$('#btn_show_passwd').mousedown(function(){
    $('#inp_passwd').hide();
    $('#inp_passwd2').show();
});
// hide clear password
$('#btn_show_passwd').mouseup(function(){
    $('#inp_passwd').show();
    $('#inp_passwd2').hide();
});
// hide hidden text-field on start
$('#btn_show_passwd').mouseup();
```

you can use setTimeout as well instead of mouseup

Comment: That's a really elegant solution. I like the use of mouse up/down instead of a toggle.

Comment: Won't work if u plan on submitting the form. The field name would have to be the same and form will pick only value of the first or last input.

Answer (score 0):

May need to display text information in the password field made ​​the picture, set to the background of the password field, and removed when the password field focus change background image, so as to achieve the effect of prompting the user

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar challenge recently and i 'd like to assess my opinion. 
I used some of the above solutions and some other using jQuery (which i like a lot). But when test time came we realize that the solutions through jQuery and `attr()` function not working. So I find the appropriate solution through pure Javascript.

```
  var input = document.getElementById('txbOldPass');
  var newInput = document.createElement('input');

        newInput.type = 'text';
        newInput.id = input.id;
        newInput.value = input.value;
        input.parentNode.replaceChild(newInput, input);
        newInput.className = 'text';
```

and the opposite

```
  var input = document.getElementById('txbOldPass');
        var newInput = document.createElement('input');
        newInput.type = 'password';
        newInput.id = input.id;
        newInput.value = input.value;
        input.parentNode.replaceChild(newInput, input);
        newInput.className = 'password';
```

Answer (score 0):

All solutions here didnt work for me (Chrome Version 51.0.2704.103 m (64-bit)). Did it like this and it works:

```
jQuery(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery('.pwForm').attr('type','password');
    }, 1);
});
```

Works on IE 11, too!

Wait for DOM ready and wait 1 millisecond. Then Change type=text to type=password

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
<input type="text" id="password_input" name="password" />
<script>
$("#password_input").click(function(){
    $(this).prop('type', 'date');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the type attribute value, only need to update your JQuery.

See the example below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="loginBox">
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="username_input" name="username" /><br />
      <input type="text" id="password_input" name="password" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#password_input").attr('type','password');
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The above answers are partially wrong when they state type attribute cannot be changed. Yes, it can be changed via prop/attr jquery method. The thing is, it is supported by all browsers but IE

Answer (score -1):

Why you guys said that "You can't change the type attribute". But when I try this, this work for me:

```
$('#eye').click(function() {
    if ($('#eye_icon').attr('name') == 'eye-off-outline') {
        $('#eye_icon').attr('name', 'eye-outline');
        $('#password').attr('type', 'text'); // when type='password' changed to 'text'
    } else {
        $('#eye_icon').attr('name', 'eye-off-outline');
        $('#password').attr('type', 'password'); // when type='text' changed to 'password'
    }
});
```