# How can I make this jQuery work in IE explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Working with the following code to dynamically change the submit buttons to image based buttons.

```
marker2 = jQuery('<span class="marker"> </span>').insertBefore('input#ResetDatesButton');
jQuery('input#ResetDatesButton').detach().attr('type', 'image').attr('src',theme_folder+'/style/images/ResetDatesButton.png').insertAfter(marker2);
marker2.remove();
```

This works beautifully in FF, Chrome and Safari but fails totally in IE6, 7 and 8. Then button is removed, but not replaced. How can I achieve the same result in IE?

Comment: Does jQuery fix this `<span />`?

Comment: do you mean does it put both parts in? it seems to.

Comment: I'd try using `<span></span>`.

Comment: you can just do `jQuery('<span>')`

Comment: What does it actually do in IE?

Comment: I have edited the question to show current position clearer.

Comment: What does it do if you don't remove the marker2 in IE?

Comment: same thing, button gone, not replaced

Comment: I thought it was `jQuery('span')`

Comment: I am creating a new element, not selecting any one element in particular.

Comment: @Mild Fuzz, you isn't creating a new element. You is *detaching* the button (wich removes it from the DOM, but don't destroy it data from memory), changing it type (**wich causes the problem, since IE doesn't allow it**), changing it image `src` and again reinserting it to the DOM.

Comment: Downvoted with no comment, nice :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE doesn't allow you to dynamically change the type attribute of form inputs.
The only option you have is to delete the element and replace it with a new one of the correct type,

Comment: I thought that was what, for all intents and purposes, this was doing?

Comment: Like I pointed, he had other options using CSS only or both CSS with jQuery to put something that you trigger the input click while the input stays hidden.

Comment: @Mild Fuzz - in your code your removing the element from the dom, editing it and then adding it back. for ie, you will need to delete the element, create a completely new one and then insert that.

Comment: here's a working example of changing type text to password: http://jsfiddle.net/9Bhya/

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer doens't allow `input[type]` changes on the fly. Here is another thread discussing it: [change type of input field with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/jquery-change-type-of-input-field)

Then, jQuery can do nothing to it works.

You will to:

- Use CSS on your `input[type=button]` to show the image you want and hide the text.
- Or hide the `input`, put an `a` tag with the image you want and set the `click()` to call the `input.click()`.

**EDIT:**

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ErickPetru/SDWjY/) is a little sample showing how to replace the `input[type=button]` with another control (you can use CSS to show it how you want) and then trigger the button click as well.

Comment: Also, is a good pratice to leave comments when downvoting, show to the question's author why this answer is incomplete.