# Changing the type of an input field using jQuery (text -> password)

Tags: jquery, html, types, input

I am trying to change type of input, specifically after click into input change **type="text" to change="password"**.

I don't know why, but I can't to add the option **type="password"** as attribute to input.

```
        $('input#id_reg_pass').removeAttr("type"); #this works, type="text" is removing
        $('input#id_reg_pass').attr('type', 'password'); #problem, this not works
        $(this).addClass('exampleText').val($(this).attr('title'));
```

Haven't someone similar problem? I'll glad for every hint... 
Thank you

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/jquery-change-type-of-input-field

Answer (score 13):

If you're using jQuery 1.6, use [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead:

```
$('input#id_reg_pass').removeAttr("type");
$('input#id_reg_pass').prop('type', 'password');
$(this).addClass('exampleText').val($(this).attr('title'));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/z8Rj3/

Comment: Thanks all for your replies. I am working with this [tutorial](http://webservices.blog.gustavus.edu/2008/06/23/text-input-example-text-with-jquery/). But even if  you help me (glad for it), I am still struggling with problem about input type="password" and text in that input... It is possible to edit this tutorial for password input at all?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot change the attribute `type` after adding the element to the DOM, if you want it to function the same way on all browsers, see [this](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1957) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534700.aspx).

> As of Microsoft Internet Explorer 5,
>   the type property is read/write-once,
>   but only when an input element is
>   created with the createElement method
>   and before it is added to the
>   document.

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same problem, I wanted to show a text in a password field until the user clicked over it. I did another approach, instead to try to change the type of the field I hide it and showed a new text field, then called the focus(). It works fine.

```
$("#password_fake").focus(){
    $(this).hide();
    $("#password").show().focus();
}
```

where #password_fake is a text field and #password a password field with style="display:none".

Comment: This is great but I get a syntax error; shouldn't your function be inside the parenthesis?  .focus(function(){ ... });

Answer (score 1):

Your code throws an error for me, `type property can't be changed`. Interestingly though, the following code does work for me on Chrome at least:

```
$('input#id_reg_pass')[0].type = 'password';
```

It could be that this doesn't work cross-browser however, which would explain why jQuery doesn't allow it (As pointed out by Niklas, this is the case). Alternatively you could construct a new `<input>` with the same attributes and replace the old one with it.

Comment: check my answer. That error is thrown by jQuery for a reason, "The exception is actually thrown by jQuery so isn't a bug but a feature letting the coder know that doesn't work."

Comment: @niklas: Yes, I saw your answer. Unfortunately, once again it's only IE that doesn't work as one might reasonably expect...

Answer (score 0):

Try this [demo is here](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/5WMZH/62/)

```
$(document).delegate('input[type="text"]','click', function() {
    $(this).replaceWith('<input type="password" value="'+this.value+'" id="'+this.id+'">');
}); 
$(document).delegate('input[type="password"]','click', function() {
    $(this).replaceWith('<input type="text" value="'+this.value+'" id="'+this.id+'">');
});
```