# Protecting/Displaying form fields

Tags: jquery, security, asp-classic

My scenario is that a Personnel form displays 3 levels of secure information, 1 basic name, department and contact, 2 personal info related to address etc, and 3, Business information including salary etc.

I have a tabbed form for these and the display works fine. The data is loaded from a database via Jquery's loadJson plugin, based on the logged on user's UserID. Finally, the user can select another user and display their data. Again, this works fine.

My requirement is to protect/display data within the tabs based on a security level in the users login profile (all my security profile works fine).

1, All users can see the data in tab 1.
2, All users can see their own data in tabs 1-3.
3, All users can update data in tab 2 of their own record.
Now for the difficult bit
4, No user can update tabs 1 and 3 of their own record.
5, A manager can see/update all tabs for a user of lower grade than themselves.
6, No user can update/see tab3 of a user of their own grade or higher.
7, Only senior managers can update all tabs.

I've tried and considered a number of approaches, including managing all of this server side, but that seems to mean generating a lot of HTML that is sloppy.

My most recent idea was to secure fields by setting the 'password' type attribute  prior to loading a record based on the users grade and the grade of the incoming record as follows;

```
if (<%=session("uid")%> != data.StaffID) {
            switch(<%=session("lid")%>) {
                case 200:
                    alert($('#StaffSalary').prop('type'));
                    $('.semisecure, .secure').removeAttr("type");
                    alert($('#StaffSalary').prop('type'));
                    $('.semisecure, .secure').prop('type', 'password');
                    alert($('#StaffSalary').prop('type'));
                    break;
                case 400:
                    $('.secure').removeAttr("type");
                    $('.secure').prop('type', 'password');
                    break;
                }
            }
        else {

        };
        $('form').loadJSON(data);
```

The StaffSalary field in initially set as type 'text'. The first alert shows it's type as text, the second alert after the removeAttr still says text and the final alert says 'password'.

However, when the tab is viewed, the data is shown as text. If I test this changing the html to password, the data loaded is shown as if a password.

Maybe this is the wrong approach, but ideas and input would be greatly appreciated.

ps. because of the nature of this, I cannot give a link to it. Sorry

Comment: What if JavaScript is disabled? I would do it server side as this will be the most secure approach. I don't think this approach would work in IE either - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402484/changing-the-type-of-an-input-field-using-jquery-text-password

Comment: Because of the nature of this, I would say you MUST do the permissions server-side, because that is the only thing you have reliable control over. (If you think you can control what the user sees purely via Javascript, you're deluding yourself.)

Comment: You cannot rely on any browser controls for security. The user could use a debugging proxy that displays all data (even SSL data) and thence will bypass all of your security. If you don't want the user to know something you can't send it to the client. There is no way around this.