# How to change an input from text to password and vice-versa?

Tags: jquery, text, input, passwords

If you visit [this site](http://netcartas.com.br/) you can see that the type of the `Senha` input is `text`. But when I type something in, it changes to `Password`.

When I click out it maintains my input and maintains it's type as `Password`.

However if there is no text and I click out, it reverts back to `text`.

Can you explain how I can easily achieve something like this? It's very good from a UX standpoint.

I'm using the latest version of jQuery.

Comment: I'm not seeing the UX advantage to this. Why is a blank text input better than a blank password one?

Comment: Search for 'changeToPassword' within the source.

Comment: @GregL: It's not blank. It shows the text: "Senha". Visit the website to see how it works from a user standpoint.

Comment: This question seems applicable and shows some of the pitfalls of this and workarounds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/jquery-change-type-of-input-field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [HTML5 placeholder text](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute). But this can have some unintended renderings when applied to password fields in some browsers, and doesn't even work at all in IE prior to IE9. So for cross-browser consistency, I'd use a jQuery plugin for it:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/html5placeholder

Then you hardly have to do anything. In you'r HTML you'd set up a regular password text field, but with a placeholder, like this:

```
<input type="password" placeholder="Senha">
```

In the javascript (after including the jQuery plugin above), you can just activate it:

```
$('input').placeholder();
```

But, if you want to use a traditional method (or if the above method doesn't work for you for some reason), you can just swap out the password field with a plain text field as required. You'd set up your HTML like this, with a visible prompt and hidden actual field:

```
<input id="password-field" type="password" name="password" style="display: none;">
<input id="password-prompt" type="text" value="Senha">
```

Then, jquery to swap it out:

```
// This makes the password field show up when you focus on the prompt,
// and changes focus to the password field
$('#password-prompt').focus(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('#password-field').show().focus();
});

// This makes the prompt re-appear when you lose focus on the password field,
// but only if it's still empty (if you typed anything in, it leaves it as is)
$('#password-field').blur(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).hide();
        $('#password-prompt').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Browser security doesn't allow you to change the input type directly. You can however use `replaceWith` to replace the input with a password type:

```
$("#input1").replaceWith($("<input>").attr({ "type" : "password", "id" : "input1" }));
```

Tested it and it does work. Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UW3dB/).

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me on iOS Safari:

```
$(function() {
    $('#tb').keypress(function() {
        $(this).prop('type', 'password');
    }).blur(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === '')
            $(this).prop('type', 'text');
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/unwJh/5/

Does it work in any other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the element, example:

http://jsfiddle.net/YEHFe/