# Why can't I change the type of an input element to submit?

Tags: jquery, types, input, submit

I'm calling this function:

```
function submit_button(button_id){
    $('#' + button_id).attr('type', 'submit');
}
```

to make this button type = submit instead of button.:

```
<input  name="confirm_button" id="confirm_button" type="button" value="Confirm" class="login_btn" />
```

and I get this error (in firefox):

uncaught exception: type property can't be changed

Are there any work arounds?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
function submit_button(button_id){
    $('#' + button_id).prop('type', 'submit');
}
```

Be aware that this changes the type but not the value, so the button will still read "confirm".

A fiddle to prove it : http://jsfiddle.net/qeUxP/

Answer (score 14):

Why jQuery won't allow you to just change the type attribute?

Because it causes problems in **Internet Explorer**.

More info at: [change type of input field with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/jquery-change-type-of-input-field)

"Straight from the jQuery source":

```
// We can't allow the type property to be changed (since it causes problems in IE)
if ( name == "type" && jQuery.nodeName( elem, "input" ) && elem.parentNode )
    throw "type property can't be changed";
```

Comment: However, you can change the `type` with `prop`, will that cause issues in IE?

Answer (score 5):

It worked finally , try finding the following:

```
   $("#confirm_button").each(function () 
   { this.type = "number"; });
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a workaround:

```
$('<input name="confirm_button" id="confirm_button2" type="submit" value="Confirm" class="login_btn" />').insertAfter('#confirm_button');
$('#confirm_button').remove();
```

Comment: Perfect this will work fine. Does anyone know why jquery won't allow you to just change the type attribute though?

Comment: It will if you use the prop() method.

Comment: Why not `replaceWith` instead of `insertAfter` and `remove`?

Comment: I was just trying to illustrate the general idea.x

Answer (score 3):

Why not just bind to the click event and call the form submit in your click handler?

Answer (score 3):

### **javascript:**

```
function submit_button(){

      var btn=document.getElementById('button_id');
      btn.setAttribute('type', 'submit');

  }
```

======================================================================

### **Jquery:**

```
function submit_button(){

 $('#' + button_id).prop('type', 'submit');

   }
```

======================================================================

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to create an element of the correct type, and replace the currently exisitng one.

However, in your example, a `<button>` element could serve the purpose of submitting the form, render as a button, and not require any javascript to do so, eg:

```
<button name="confirm_button" id="confirm_button" type="input" value="Confirm" class="login_btn" disabled />
```

And then to make the button enabled again:

```
$('confirm_button').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: This button is hidden up until the user clicks another button. Then this button is shown so the user can click it to submit the form. The problem Im having is that this submit button is still triggered by pressing the enter key even when it is still hidden @davidethell

Comment: @davidethell, you could just add the `disabled` attribute to your hidden button. Answer updated.