# Does javascript forbid changing the input type from password or to password?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, input, passwords

I am using this code on the input element:

```
onmouseout="
$('#passwordhelp').text('');
$('#rpassword').attr('type', 'password')"
```

Comment: How about you try it out on a small html file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery change type of input field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/jquery-change-type-of-input-field)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the property `type` with jquery in the way you are attempting to do it. You're bumping into a browser issue:

See [JQuery change type of input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/jquery-change-type-of-input-field)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery 1.6 or above? If so try [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/). In your case like this [(Example)](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/9vkFW/):

```
onmouseout="
$('#passwordhelp').text('');
$('#rpassword').prop('type', 'password')"
```

Though it won't work on IE8 and below.

IMHO you shouldn't use javascript and jQuery like this. Bind your events on [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). But of course it's your choice...

Comment: Does jQuery actually go out of its way to check if `prop` is called as a setter on an input element with `"type"` as a key? Otherwise it won't work at least in IE.

Comment: Why is -1? This code works on latest versions of all browsers. There is an example and a warning for IE8 and below. So, the -1 caster, can you please explain yourself, why down vote?