# Handle OnClick in C# or JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, standards

I am working on a webforms project using c#/aspx/jquery. I'm not sure where to handle my `Onclick`. Both options (doing it in C# or jquery) seem feasible. Which would be better practice?

Here is the scenario:

I want to build a `checkbox` which will toggle a `textbox's textmode`, altering it between Password and SingleLine.

Currently, I have this following code for my markup since I am currently handling it in C#:

```
<asp:Checkbox ID="CheckBox1" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_OnCheckedChanged"/>
```

The code:

```
protected virtual void OnCheckedChange(EventArgs e)
{
     If (CheckBox1.TextMode == TextMode.Password)
          CheckBox1.TextMode = TextMode.SingleLine;
     else
          CheckBox1.TextMode = TextMode.Password;
}
```

The use case of this is: A user is entering his password. On the same page, he may choose to keep the password hidden or not by checking the checkbox.

Comment: You probably want to do this in jQuery as it is client logic and you don't want/need a postback. This post may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541514/jquery-change-input-type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Which would be better practice?*

What is your functional requirement?

- Setting this in C# on the asp.net code behind, you will need a post-back to make it work. This means the page will refresh and the text box will change.
- On the client (JS/JQuery) the page will not refresh.

Now you evaluate the work required vs the quality you need. (If you want a nice user experience and are ok with writing JS put it in JS, if you're strapped for time and are ok with the refresh then do it on asp.net).

*I'm trying to answer your question in general sense about HOW such a decision (in my humble opinion) should be made.* **Realistically** this is very simple to implement in javascript and your should do it there.

---

**Now for the code** (I assume you know how to put it in asp.net code behind so I'm going to write the JS approach):

Html:

```
My Password: <input type="password" id="mytext" /> <br />
Hide Chars : <input id="passChk" type="checkbox" checked="true" />
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $("#passChk").change(function(){
        if(this.checked) {
            $("#mytext").attr("type","password");
        } else {
            $("#mytext").attr("type","text");
        }
    });
});
```

See it running here: http://jsfiddle.net/rC5NW/2/

Answer (score 0):

After trying to implement the accepted answer, I realized that some browsers (I used Google Chrome) does not allow changing the type attribute. There is a way to bypass this but I don't think it is worth it for my purposes:

Therefore, It might be better to just use C#.

**Relevant Questions**

- [Does javascript forbid changing the input type from password or to password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548469/does-javascript-forbid-changing-the-input-type-from-password-or-to-password)
- [change type of input field with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/jquery-change-type-of-input-field)