# how to make a jquery hint password with asterisks

Tags: javascript, jquery

example: http://jsfiddle.net/na2tD/

currently the password is not asterisks as 'type' for password text field needs to be type="text"  so it cannot be changed to type="password" which is needed if i want asterisks. How do I get both jquery hint and asterisks working together

Comment: What does jQuery 'hint' do? Is this a plugin of some kind?

Comment: @westo: because in his implementation the watermark text will be displayed in asterisks too.

Comment: this might be interesting to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2304369/306848 Seems to be a similar problem

Comment: @Jacob, if one of these answers was what you were looking for, please accept it to both improve your accept ratio, and give people the points they deserve :)

Answer (score 4):

You can leverage the new HTML5 attribute, called `placeholder`. No Javascript required!

```
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password" size="20" />
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/na2tD/8/

Comment: This will not work in quite a few browsers as they don't have support for HTML 5

Comment: @westo: quite a few? [Only IE (among desktop browsers) still doesn't support it](http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder).

Comment: Or older versions of Firefox.  I know many people still on 3.6 :\  But I agree, we should all be pushing towards [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement)

Comment: By quite a few, I was referring to the number of internet users that are using browsers that don't support this feature. http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201102-201202-bar

Answer (score 2):

That's a poor implementation of hinting.  First of all, if someone submits an empty form they will actually be submitting "Username" and "Password" as parameters, and it'll be annoying to filter those out server-side.

Better to just go with the `placeholder` attribute:  http://jsfiddle.net/na2tD/6/

```
<input type="password" name="password" title="Password" size="10" placeholder="Password"/>
```

EDIT:

And if you need it to support older browsers that don't support the html5 `placeholder` attribute, you can add this js:  https://github.com/parndt/jquery-html5-placeholder-shim

Comment: it also goes against any previous user experience where asterisks in a password field indicate a auto-filled user/pass combo. anything apart from the placeholder tag would be rather confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this GitHub page.  I think this is what you are after.

https://github.com/nachokb/jquery-hint-with-password

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use HTML5 placeholder, you can change the type of the input using "regular" JavaScript: `input.type = 'password'`. Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/brunomsilva/na2tD/5/ .

Comment: That WILL NOT WORK in internet explorer.  You can't dynamicaly change the type of an input (at least that's my understanding)

Answer (score 0):

Use the placeholder attribute.  Of course, that doesn't work in IE, and there are many solutions out there to overcome IE's lack of support.  Most of these are not very good, especially those that change the value of the input element to accomplish the placeholder text.  This approach is buggy and has accessibility issues.

The better approach is to use a technique that doesn't modify the input's value.  It should work automatically with forms that already use the `placeholder` attribute with no additional changes to the markup.  The technique I use is to place a label behind the input so that it shows through the input.  When the input has focus or a value, it gets a background color to hide the placeholder label.

First I check to see if the browser natively supports `placeholder`.  This code tells us whether placeholder is supported:

```
if (!("placeholder" in document.createElement("input"))) {
    // placeholder is not natively supported
}
```

If `placeholder` is not supported, I inject an absolutely positioned `<label>` before each `<input>` that has a `placeholder` attribute and I add a `noplaceholder` class to the input indicating that placeholder is not natively supported and that the label should show through the input.  I use CSS to style the label to match the input and decrease the opacity of the input so that the label shows through.  The rest is just pretty straightforward event handling to add or remove the `noplaceholder` class depending on whether the input has focus and/or a value.

Here's my code.  Drop the following CSS and JavaScript into an existing page that uses placeholder attributes and it should work.  The CSS may require a little tweaking to get it to work on your page.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/yjfvm/2/

The CSS:

```css
input[placeholder], .placeholder {
    font-family: Sans-Serif;
    border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 2px 4px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
}
.placeholder + input[placeholder].noplaceholder {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #b2b2b2;
}
.placeholder + input[placeholder] {
    position: relative;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    border-color: #666;
}
.placeholder, label.placeholder {
    border-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-left: 0;
    top: auto;
}
```

The JavaScript:

```
if (!("placeholder" in document.createElement("input"))) {
    $(function() {
        $("input[placeholder]").each(function() {
            $("<label>")
                .attr("for", this.id)
                .addClass("placeholder")
                .text(this.getAttribute("placeholder"))
                .insertBefore(this);
            $(this).addClass("noplaceholder");
        }).on("keydown focus input", function() {
            $(this).addClass("noplaceholder");
        }).on("change blur", function() {
            if (!this.value) {
                $(this).removeClass("noplaceholder");
            }
        }).change();
        $("form").on("reset", function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("input[placeholder]:not(:focus)").change();
            }, 0);
        });
    });
}
```