# Change input type for all text fields into password fields

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, bookmarklet

I need code that changes all text input fields into password input fields (hidden with Asterisk) if they are text type (preferably a javascript bookmarklet).

P.S: I use Google Chrome, and I don't know anything about placing jquery in chrome

Answer (score 1):

Here is a related topic : [change type of input field with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/jquery-change-type-of-input-field)

> It's very likely this action is prevented as part of the browser's
>   security model.
>
> Edit: indeed, testing right now in Safari, I get the error type
>   property cannot be changed.
>
> Edit 2: that seems to be an error straight out of jQuery. Using the
>   following straight DOM code works just fine:

```
var pass = document.createElement('input');
pass.type = 'password';
document.body.appendChild(pass);
pass.type = 'text';
pass.value = 'Password';
```

> Edit 3: Straight from the jQuery source, this seems to be related to
>   IE (and could either be a bug or part of their security model, but
>   jQuery isn't specific):

```
// We can't allow the type property to be changed (since it causes problems in IE)
if ( name == "type" && jQuery.nodeName( elem, "input" ) && elem.parentNode )
    throw "type property can't be changed";
```