# How to create HTML for a "show password" functionality?

Tags: jquery, html, button, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery change type of input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/jquery-change-type-of-input-field)

Demo here:

http://jsbin.com/welcome/73795/edit

---

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="password" name="password" />
<button>Show Password</button>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('input').attr('type', 'text');
  });
});
```

---

I'm trying to create a button (or checkbox) that users will be able to toggle to see their password written in plain text.

This is basically for portable devices where typing in passwords is a pain, and seeing it in plain text while writing is a UX improvement.

In my example above, changing the type of the input doesn't work.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Try using two input elements with their contents in sync, and alternately hide one and show the other.

Comment: jQuery doesn't allow that. Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/jquery-change-type-of-input-field

Comment: @TJ- Actually that's close enough to be a dupe.

Comment: Check this video:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5YeSqtB0kfE

Comment: 2017 - Changing the input type now works. I adapted a little bit the solution in Grijesh video: https://jsfiddle.net/herLkape/. Tested with IE11, GC 59 and FF54.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't change `type` attribute..
See workaround here : http://jsfiddle.net/Ngtp7/2/

and a variation here : http://jsfiddle.net/Ngtp7/

Comment: Actually, your second example does just that: i.e. to change the type attribute.

Comment: Please take a better look, the script is creating a new element and deleting the previous one. Nice answer!