# How check first input in append html

Tags: jquery

I would like selected after append template the first input (**class is time**).

How to do this?

```
$.get('@Url.Action("Bonus")', function (template) {
                $("#bonuses").append(template);
                // I would like focused first input in template $(template).first().focus();
            });
```

html in template:

```
<input autocomplete="off" name="BonusList.Bonuses.Index" type="hidden" value="3c6f7b63-cc96-4971-a5b5-2e4640ca97e5" />
<input class="time" id="BonusList_Bonuses_3c6f7b63-cc96-4971-a5b5-2e4640ca97e5__ID" name="BonusList.Bonuses[3c6f7b63-cc96-4971-a5b5-2e4640ca97e5].ID" type="hidden" value="0" />
```

3c6f7b63-cc96-4971-a5b5-2e4640ca97e5 - is random GUID

**it's important** #bonuses have many input befor this append

Comment: Can you show the markup for the template?

Comment: I add in post html source from template

Comment: i don't think a hidden input can gain the focus :-/

Comment: sorry I mean input with class time

Comment: I added and edit to my answer to reflect your changes (the time class, find the last one of those)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below snippet

```
$(template).find('input:first').focus();
```

If your first input is not of type text and you need to focus only first text type input use below code instead

```
$(template).find('input[type=text]:first').focus();
```

Comment: I guess your first input element in your template is not of type and you need to focus first text input.If i am getting you right then you can do like this `$(template).find('input[type=text]:first').focus();`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the type on an input, SO, instead, hide it using a CSS class (in your template), then you can show it. (reference: [change type of input field with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/jquery-change-type-of-input-field))

```
<input autocomplete="off" name="BonusList.Bonuses.Index" type="text" class="iamhidden" value="3c6f7b63-cc96-4971-a5b5-2e4640ca97e5" /><input id="BonusList_Bonuses_3c6f7b63-cc96-4971-a5b5-2e4640ca97e5__ID" name="BonusList.Bonuses[3c6f7b63-cc96-4971-a5b5-2e4640ca97e5].ID" type="text" class="iamhidden" value="0" />
```

CSS:

```
.iamhidden{display:none;}
```

and the selector for that:  find the first of the two inputs, given they are the last two in appended, remove the hide class, then focus it (the next to last one):

```
$('#bonuses').find('input:last').prev().removeClass("iamhidden").focus();
```

I put a really simplified fiddle to show this logic working: http://jsfiddle.net/seAxW/

EDIT: to reflect your comments, focus the one with class "time" (you would still need the CSS and type text)

```
$('#bonuses').find('input.time:last').removeClass("iamhidden").focus();
```

with the hidden class added: Just put a space between the "time" and "iamhidden" classes, you COULD

```
<input autocomplete="off" name="BonusList.Bonuses.Index" type="hidden" value="3c6f7b63-cc96-4971-a5b5-2e4640ca97e5" />
<input class="time iamhidden" id="BonusList_Bonuses_3c6f7b63-cc96-4971-a5b5-2e4640ca97e5__ID" name="BonusList.Bonuses[3c6f7b63-cc96-4971-a5b5-2e4640ca97e5].ID" type="text" value="0" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

```
$.get('@Url.Action("Bonus")', function (template) {
    $("#bonuses").append(template);
    $("#bonuses").find('input:first').focus();
});
```