# Changing Attributes for two inputs fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm have some problems to add attributes to these input fields using jQuery:

```
<input id='timetable_start'>
<input id='timetable_finish'>

<script>
attributes = {
    "class": "reloj",
    "maxlength": "5",
    "pattern": "^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$",
    "size": "6",
    "type": "text"
};

$('#timetable_finish').attr(attributes);
$('#timetable_start').attr(attributes);
</script>
```

Why only one is changed? What I'm missing? Thanks in advance for you time
Link: 
http://jsbin.com/iqipan/4/edit

Comment: When you say "Why only one is changed?" do you mean only one attribute, or only one element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the code throws an error when you are trying to set the attributes for the first input field:

> Uncaught Error: type property can't be changed.

Remove `type` from the object and everything will be fine.

---

Some browsers (I guess IE) don't allow to change the type of an `input` element after it was created, so jQuery throws an exception if you are trying to do that. See [change type of input field with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/jquery-change-type-of-input-field).

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
$("#timetable_finish, #timetable_start").attr(attributes);
```

However, you can't change the `type` property of inputs.  You would have to create a new input instead:

```
$("#timetable_finish").replaceWith($("<input>", attributes));
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because the *attribute* `type` is read-only - whereas the *DOM property* `type` is not.

You can use:

```
$('#timetable_finish').prop(attributes);
$('#timetable_start').prop(attributes);
```

to successfully change both.

Comment: Ha, I didn't know the property can be changed... still, it does not mean you should do that ;)

Comment: @FelixKling - I thought it couldn't be. Till about 6 mins back. :-)

Comment: @Christian_Espinoza - This will likely fail in IE. Atleast older versions.