# Angular.js Dynamic Form input types

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make an Angular.js app that creates dynamic form inputs from a JSON object.

So firstly, I have a JSON object (called fields):

```
[
  {"field_id":209,"form_id":1,"name":"firstname","label":"First Name","type":"text"},
  {"field_id":210,"form_id":1,"name":"lastname","label":"Last Name","type":"text"},
  {"field_id":211,"form_id":1,"name":"email","label":"Email","type":"text"},
  {"field_id":212,"form_id":1,"name":"picture","label":"Picture","type":"file"},
  {"field_id":213,"form_id":1,"name":"address","label":"Address","type":"file"},
  {"field_id":214,"form_id":1,"name":"password","label":"Password","type":"password"},
  {"field_id":215,"form_id":1,"name":"","label":"","type":"submit"}
]
```

The object key `type` is the input type for a form. See below:

```
<p ng-repeat="field in fields">
  {{field.name}} : <input type="{{field.type}}" value="{{record.data[field.name]}}" />
</p>
```

Now this works completely fine for `submit`, `text`, `password`, `checkbox` and `radio` fields. But if the type is `file`, it sets the input type to `text`.

If I replace `{{field.name}}` with `{{field.type}}` for the text, I can confirm it is outputting `file`.

If I statically change `<input type="{{field.type}}"...`  to `<input type="file"...` it will display a file input correctly.

Why won't it let me set an input type as a file dynamically?

Comment: Works fine for me, what version of AngularJS are you using?

Comment: Actually it is browser depended... somewhere it works, somewhere not.

Answer (score 2):

Topic if changing `type` property if `<input>` element is hot topic.

Actually, as AngularJS behaviour depends on was jQuery added (before or after angular.js).

Here you can read some discussion about possibility to change `type`: 
[change type of input field with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/jquery-change-type-of-input-field)

Also there is pull request to AngularUI for adding new directive with support of dynamic type change: https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/pull/371

If you find suggested solution is not good enough (though as type is not changed after you render form) you can go with `ng-switch` way - just show corrent input for user.