# How to use ng-bind in HTML param values

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind

I want to use ng-bind directive instead of brackets {{ }} in AngularJS. We have example:

```
<tag type="{{value1}}">{{value2}}</tag>
```

Change value2 is easy. We have:

```
<tag type="{{value1}}" ng-bind="value2"></tag>
```

How can we change `{{value1}}` to remove brackets notation?

The first solution by DonJuwe does not working correct for me. Maybe I am doing something wrong. For example in HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
    1. <p style="{{style}}">{{style}}</p>
    2. <p style="getStyle()" ng-bind="style"></p>
    3. <p style="getStyle()" ng-bind="getStyle()"></p>
    <input type="button" ng-click="setStyle()" value="Change Style" />
</div>
```

in controller:

```
var module = angular.module('myApp', []);

module.controller('TestController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.style = 'color: rgb(0, 0, 0)';

    $scope.getStyle = function() {
        return $scope.style;
    };

    $scope.setStyle = function() {
        $scope.style = 'color: rgb('+Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)+', 0, 0)';
    }
});
```

After click on button, all texts (1., 2., 3.) are correct but only line 1 changing color to random red.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952562/angular-js-dynamic-form-input-types

Comment: please tell us why you don't want to use curly brackets. maybe there is another solution for your problem.

Comment: Apparently ng-bind is better and faster than using curly brackets, what with conflict with Twig notation in my case induce me to find other/better way than change AngularJS or Twig interpolation signs to e.g. '{[{' and '}]}' :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a *function* in your *controller* which returns the value:

```
<tag type="getValue()" ng-bind="value2"></tag>
```

And in your *controller*:

```
$scope.getValue = function() {
    return type;
}
```

Comment: It does not work for me. I added example in question

Comment: I thought that maybe my browser is a reason but your site on Firefox 36, Chromium 41, and Chrome 40 on my phone, gives the same result: texts are ok but only first text changes color after click. Could you confirm that in Your browser color changes for all texts every time?

Comment: you are right, it does not work this way. is a directive a suitable way for you?

Comment: Thanks, now it works! I will copy Your solution code here in new answer

Answer (score 0):

DonJuwe's resolve:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
    1. <p style="{{style}}">{{style}}</p>
    2. <p style="{{style}}" ng-bind="style"></p>
    3. <p my-style ng-bind="style"></p>
    <input type="button" ng-click="setStyle()" value="Change Style" />
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('myStyle', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            color: '=ngBind'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem) {
            elem.attr('style', scope.color);
            scope.$watch('color', function() {
                elem.attr('style', scope.color);
            });
        }
    }
});

function TestController($scope) {    
    $scope.style = 'color: rgb(0, 0, 0)';

    $scope.setStyle = function() {
        $scope.style = 'color: rgb(' + 
            Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 
            ', ' + 
            Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 
            ', ' + 
            Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 
            ')';
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!