# How to change the input type property in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, placeholder

I have a login form with username and password fields. I am using a placeholder to show help text for each input. It's working fine in Firefox, and Chrome, but not in IE, as placeholder is a HTML5 input property. I am writing a custom function to work the placeholder in IE. On that particular function I want to change the password field input type from "password" to "text" in jQuery.

Please suggest a solution for this.

Comment: You do know that unsupported browsers will automatically fallback to the text type ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery change type of input field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/jquery-change-type-of-input-field)

Comment: Just use a js placeholder plugin like this one: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('input:password').prop('type','text');
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/47hem/

Comment: @thatidiotguy: [See this](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#input-attr-type-newvalue-in-oldie)

Comment: @PalashMondal Hey, thanks for following up with that. Interesting little quirk to know about there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#id").attr("type", "text");
```

EDIT:

```
$("#id").remove();
$("#containerOfInput").append("<input type="text" ........");
```

And you don't have to use append. You could use `.html("newHTML")` if you have a container that is holding just that input field.

Comment: I have tried this, it's not working. It is throwing an error that "can't change property type". I think this is because of some browser security issue.

Comment: Quite possibly! I have never tried it. You might better off removing the original, and then adding. Let me edit.

Comment: I got it working. Here is the solution someone suggested above.

$('input:password').prop('type','text');

Comment: @thatidiotguy: Your first code should work, if OP is using jQuery v.1.9 or above.. as I have [mentioned earlier](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#input-attr-type-newvalue-in-oldie)

Comment: @DeepakBiswal: You have already got an answer I know, but just wanted to know which version of jQuery file are you using currently in your code?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$("#input_field_id").attr("type", "text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like below should do the trick,

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/7t6hk/

```
    $('#password').focus(function () {
        this.type = 'password'
        $(this).removeClass('placeholder').val(function () {
            var val = $.trim(this.value);
            return (val == 'Password')?'':this.value;
        });
    }).blur (function () {
        $(this).val(function () {
            var val = $.trim(this.value);
            return (val == '')?'Password':this.value;
        });

        if (this.value == 'Password') {
            $(this).addClass('placeholder')
            this.type = 'text';
        }
    });
```

Just noticed that you want the part to change the type. You could do that by setting `this.type`.

- Set `this.type = 'text'`  for textfield
- Set `this.type = 'password'` for password field