# how to change button into text format when on click the button

Tags: php, jquery, html

Is their any possible when on click the button it change to only text and not as a button.

Ex:

I have Invite button for all individual user. What I need is when on click the Invite button, button text need not to change instead button is change to text.

"Invite" button format is change to "pending request" text format along with "cancel" button when on click the button.

Comment: Why not create a button and a text. Then you can choose which is which to show/hide.

Comment: make two butons and on click of one change the buttons.

Comment: refer link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/jquery-change-type-of-input-field

Comment: Hide it as suggested by @JunM. Also make sure you disable the initial button when hiding to prevent double-click or Enter key. This is a relatively easy task with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps, this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vonDy2791/kRKJg/1/)**

if you want to learn more. read more about [jquery](http://jquery.com/).

html

```
<input id="invite" type="button" value="Invite" />
<span id="pending">Pending</span>
<input id="cancel" type="button" value="Cancel" />
```

script

```
$('#pending').hide();
$('#cancel').hide();

$('#invite').on('click', function () {
    $(this).hide('fast');
    $('#pending').show('fast');
    $('#cancel').show('fast');
});

$('#cancel').on('click', function () {
    $(this).hide('fast');
    $('#pending').hide('fast');
    $('#invite').show('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith("pending request<button>cancel</button>")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btnAddProfile").click(function(){
    $("#btnAddProfile").attr('value', 'pending request...');
//add cancel button
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a button like this:

```
<button>Click me</button>
```

You can disable it on click with jQuery like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();       
    $(this).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
});
```

See fiddle here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/jpmFS/

Or replace it with only text like this:

```
$(function() {
 $('button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();       
    $(this).replaceWith('<p>'+$(this).text()+'</p>');
 });
});
```