# Changing type of an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the type of an input on click of a button but it doesn't work. I tried this:

```
$('.addPhoto').click(function(){
 $(this).siblings('.auto_image').prop("type", "file");
});
```

It doesn't do anything at all. I searched on google and came across this:
[change type of input field with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/jquery-change-type-of-input-field)

It says it is possible to do it with straight DOM, but how would I select the class of a sibling with DOM?

Comment: try attr instead of prop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the element all together but I don't think you can just change the type attribute see my example.

```
$('.addPhoto').on("click",function(){
    $(this).off("click").replaceWith("<input type='file' class='addPhoto'/>");
});
```

or

```
$('.addPhoto').one("click",function(){
    $(this).replaceWith("<input type='file' class='addPhoto'/>");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ECzP4/

here is the jQuery documentation for `replaceWith()` http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Comment: Wow why didn't I think of that haha. Thanks a lot I will try this. I did use replaceWith before but not off. I looked it up and it's just when you release the button as much as I understood from it

Comment: @Xegano no problem, Hope it answers your question.

Comment: Using `.on()` is unnecessary...just use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) that way you don't need to call `.off()`

Comment: @milkshake sure thing, great solution btw!

Answer (score 1):

To get the dom object just take the first item from your jQuery collection:

```
var domObject = $(this).siblings('.auto_image')[0]
```

Although it doesn't seem to be able to change from `text` to `file` - http://jsfiddle.net/7HTgA/

So what I would recommend is having two inputs, and show/hide them as required rather than trying to change the type of a single input.

Answer (score 0):

Adds all its siblings with the `auto_image` class with the type - file.

```
$(this).siblings('.auto_image').attr('type','file')
```