# IE8 Password field showing entered value instead of showing asterisks

Tags: php, html, css, internet-explorer-8

In my site the password field is showing the entered value instead of showing asterisks symbol. This works fine with all the other browsers. IE7, and IE9 works as well too. Only in IE8 i'm not getting it.. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

For ref: just check the site and click on sign in the login box will appear you can check the issue with that password field.

```
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="Password" 
onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.style.color='#bbb'; this.value='Password'; this.type='text'} 
else {this.type='password';}" 
onfocus="if (this.value == 'Password') {this.style.color='#000'; this.value=''; this.type='password'} else {this.type='password';}" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
```

Comment: @BenFortune i didnt want you to signin, if u just click on that button a popup will appear there you can see the issue

Comment: You have error in line 291 for IE..

Comment: You have `<input type="text" name="password"` on your actual site. You might want to try using `type="password"` and then using a real placeholder polyfill script instead of that inline JavaScript nonsense.

Comment: @DipeshParmar — `this` is a very fundamental part of JavaScript. IE does support it.

Comment: @ManigandanArjunan Why are you setting this.type on blur and focus? Directly set type="password" in your tag

Comment: @thirtydot when start type something in that field the input type will get changed to type="password"

Comment: @MrLister: On the actual site, there's no `type="password"` in the HTML. The funky inline JavaScript may or may not add it.

Comment: changing the `type` of an `input` is not portable across browsers. You should find a better way to do this.

Comment: @Quentin well i just pasted error which i got in IE status bar....even i know IE support that....i just forget to mention that IE shows that error..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/change-type-of-input-field-with-jquery?lq=1

Comment: @thirty sorry, I was looking at it in the wrong way.

Comment: @ManigandanArjunan: Your current JavaScript is not robust and is likely to fail or behave undesirably in a range of circumstances. Use a real placeholder script instead: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing here because I don't want to go through all your code but I imagine you are replacing a `<input type="text" />` with `<input type="password" />` when the user has focus on the `input`. I don't think that is the best cross browser solution.

If you want to support older browsers you will need to use a javascript solution as the HTML5 `placeholder` value won't work on all browsers.

A good solution is using the `<label>` tag positioned under the `input` instead of faking it. For a good example see: http://blog.stannard.net.au/2011/01/07/creating-a-form-with-labels-inside-text-fields-using-jquery/

The advantages of this solution includes cross browser compatibility, accessibility and semantic markup.