# Swapping attributes of jQuery Selection elements

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, html, .net-2.0

### Background

I'm working on a web application written in .NET 2.0 that uses standard [WebControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on its pages. It'll be eventually migrated to 4.x, but right now I need to adapt some of its mobile behavior - and my first requirement is to make use of [HTML5 form input types](http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/) in order to benefit from custom onscreen keyboard formats.

My chosen approach to this problem is to dynamically change the input type of the rendered elements. My current limitations are:

- According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/change-type-of-input-field-with-jquery), jQuery can't change an `input` element's `type` because of Internet Explorer restrictions.
- `HtmlInputControl` (which is the referenced type when you just add `runat='server'` to any HTML element) doesn't support the new values for the `type` property.
- If I just add the `type` property with the desired new type to a standard `TextBox` control, it'll render the `type` property twice.

So I went with a jQuery approach. My idea is to implement a valid TextBox control with an extra tag, nexttype, like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" nexttype="phone" runat="server">
```

At runtime, it's rendered like this:

```
<input name="TextBox1" type="text" id="TextBox1" nexttype="phone">
```

And then clone the rendered elements, replacing their type property with the proper nextype counterpart, like this:

```
<input name="TextBox1" type="phone" id="TextBox1">
```

I imagine that my jQuery code should look something like this:

```
$(':not([nexttype=""])').clone().attr('type', selectedelement.attr('nexttype')).insertAfter(selectedelement).prev().remove();
```

**selectedelement**, in this case, is just a placeholder for what I imagine would be the 'currently selected' element on the selection.

The basic idea is:

- pick an element
- clone it
- change the clone's Type property
- insert the clone into the document just after the original
- remove the original

So, yeah, I suck at jQuery. =)

### Questions

- My jQuery one-liner is, of course, non-functional. What am I doing wrong?
- Is there a better approach?
- Is there something already out there that does exactly this and I'm wasting time reinventing the wheel?

### Requirements

- I can't upgrade to .NET 4.x right now; I'm limited to 2.0.
- I would prefer a solution that doesn't involve adding external assemblies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I consider a somewhat clunky solution. Basically I iterate through each member element, manipulate the clone and remove the original:

```
<script>
    $(':not([nexttype=""])').each(
        function () {
            var _c = $(this).clone();
            _c.attr('type', $(this).attr('nexttype'));
            _c.removeAttr('nexttype');
            _c.insertAfter($(this)).prev().remove();
        });
</script>
```

Still accepting more elegant solutions than this.