# add type to DOM element with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to append a `type=checkbox` to the last `td` of every `tr`

Ive been playing around with the idea of traversing in achieving this, but I have no idea if it can work. Something along the lines of this.

```
$('#myID tr').children("td:nth-last-of-type(1)").addClass("me");
```

I know this is adding a class to the element, but can it be done in a similar way to add a `TYPE` to the `tr` DOM element?
There is one or two examples out there like [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/change-type-of-input-field-with-jquery) one, but its all around changing the type and not adding a new one.

```
<table id="myID" class="myClass">
    <tr>
        <th>one</th>
        <th>two</th>
        <th>three</th>
        <th>four</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td type='checkbox'></td>    <!--  **THIS IS WAHT IM AFTER**  -->
    </tr> 
</table>

<input type='button' id='but_id' value='Click Me'/>
```

Comment: it's setting, not changing and It should work... Have you tried it out? (talking about the example in the link)

Comment: use `.attr("type",'checkbox')` instead of `.addClass("me")`

Comment: I don't think `<td>` elements are meant to have the `type="checkbox"`?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy - Simple does it hey. Thanks so much.

Comment: `<td>` does not have `type` attribute at all. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td

Comment: @RobSchmuecker - I should add a `input` element inside the `tr` hey...? TRUE

Comment: @mornenel yes! Sterkte van Plettenberg Baai!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add `type="checkbox` to td, it's useless and invalid but you can add checkbox to `td` e.g.

```
$('#myID tr').children("td:nth-last-of-type(1)").append('<input type="checkbox" />');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can append an input element to the td.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myID tr').children("td:nth-last-of-type(1)").append("<input type='checkbox'/>");
    });
```

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/qVIUDfAxp2vUIxw2AQEp?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can't add `type = 'checkbox'` in td it is invalid. Just append the input type in the td

```
$('#myID tr').find("td").last().append("<input type='checkbox' />");
```

evert last td means

```
 $('#myID tr').find("td:nth-last-child(1)").append("<input type='checkbox' />");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GTqGW/)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `type = 'checkbox'` doesn't mean anything its wrong html. you can add checkbox in td.

```
$('#myID tr').children("td:last-child").append('<input type="checkbox" />');
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L33dh/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean appending a checkbox to the last cell?  Try this.

```
$("#myID tr td:last-child").append("<input type='checkbox' />");
```

http://jsbin.com/zerocasu/2/edit