# Change the value of an attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have created a password field with id `pass`, and a checkbox with id `check`:

```html
<input type="password" id="pass"> 
<input type="checkbox" id="check" />Show Password
```

This jQuery code is used to change the password field into text field when the check box is checked, but this is not functioning correctly. The password remains as a password field even after the checkbox is checked.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#check').change(function () {
        $('#pass').attr('type','text');
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [change type of input field with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/change-type-of-input-field-with-jquery)

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/07chet0n/

Comment: I bet the `jQuery` library isn't included.

Comment: Give the browser console a look and check for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Add this `jQuery` library in the starting of your html file.

```
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

So this should be the code in your html file -

```
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<input type="password" id="pass"> 
<input type="checkbox" id="check" />Show Password
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#check').change(function () {
      if($('#pass').attr("type")=="text") {
        $('#pass').attr('type','password');
      } else {
        $('#pass').attr('type','text');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

I have tested this code and it is working perfectely.

Comment: solution doesn't give any indication of why OP code doesn't work, you are using the same methods

Comment: don't know..same code worked in jsfiddle.net @charlietfl

Comment: I don't know why the code was not working. May be Ashish missed to add `jQuery` library or would have missed any tag like we have script tags in my code. @charlietfl

Comment: @AshishGupta, Can you please share your code that you were trying and was not working? with that code we can figure out the issue very well.

Comment: code within body of html                                        <input type="password" id="pass">
<input type="checkbox" id="check" />Show Password
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="selector.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script> @prashant