# How transform the same button in a text jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to transform this :

```
<input type="button" value="O">
```

In a text. Anyone can help me?

Comment: What does "transform" mean in this context?

Comment: And what does in a text mean ?

Comment: I would that this button in a page became a text (only text)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood the question correctly following snippet you should do the trick:

```
$('input[type=button][value=0]').replaceWith(function() {
    return document.createTextNode(this.outerHTML);
});
```

The above snippet basically replaces the element with it's string representation.

http://jsfiddle.net/aet4u3e1/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input')[0].outerHTML
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p4yywzt7/)

[Get selected element's outer HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)

Answer (score 0):

Using the following straight DOM code works just fine:

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'button';
document.body.appendChild(input);
input.type = 'text';
input.value = 'this is text';
```

more infos [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/change-type-of-input-field-with-jquery)

Comment: @Fuffy you want to change the type of input to text instead of button are't you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use in pure HTML like this.

```
<pre>
    &ltinput type="button" value="O"&gt
</pre>
```

Using java script you can find and replace < >.

```
Ex: HTML.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;');
```