# Detect changing input type - jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, password-protection

I want to detect if user has changed the type of some input from `<input type="password">` to `<input type="text">` or else to put it again on `<input type="password">`.

The idea is to prevent the user from changing the type. Here is my idea or if you have something else Iam interested.

My code:

```
jQuery(('.input_class').attr('type').val()).live('change', function(){
        alert('the type is changed');
        jQuery('.input_class').prop('type', 'password');
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change type of input field with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/change-type-of-input-field-with-jquery)

Comment: it's not what i need thanks to remove a possible duplicate @Steven Johnston