# Change TextBox TextMode with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I was wondering if someone knew the best way to switch from using the

```
    myTextBox.TextMode = TextBoxMode.Password;
```

to

```
  myTextBox.TextMode = TextBoxMode.SingleLine;
```

using client code and jQuery. I will have to do it on focus, along with deleting the whole text content of the textbox onFocus event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#idOfYourTextbox').attr('type', 'text');
```

However, you **cannot** change the type of `type="password"` fields in IE (yay for useless "security" features).

Comment: it's good, because I dont need to toggle from password to text and back - only from password to text once. So sounds like it's going to work...

Comment: I get type property can't be changed exception from the jQuery framework. Any ideas?

Comment: As I said, you cannot convert `password` to `text` in IE. You'd have to retrieve the value using `.val()`, delete the element and replace it with a new element.

Answer (score 1):

These webcontrols render completly different: the TextBox with mode SingleLine renders as an an input element with type=text, TextMode.Password changes the rendering to an input element with type=password.

So although in asp.net it is a single property, in jquery you will have to change the attribute type:

> $('input.someclass').attr('type','password');

There are however some security limitations. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540851/jquery-change-element-type-from-hidden-to-input).

If you also would like to change to TextMode.Multiline, you will have to change the input element to a textarea element.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. Best thing to do is have two text boxes and then hide one on focus and show the other then focus it manually.

```
$('input:password').focus(function() {
     $(this).hide();
     $(this).siblings('input:text').show().focus();
});
```

This assumes they are both in the same container and the text box is hidden to start with.