# jQuery change input type=text to textarea

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I have a hidden field . After a drop event it needs to be transformed to a 'textarea'.

This:

```
      excerpt = $(parent).find('#excerpt').attr('type', 'textarea');
      excerpt.val('textarea');
```

Produces the

> property cannot be changed

error

This method : 
[Change element type from hidden to input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540851/jquery-change-element-type-from-hidden-to-input)

```
marker = $('<span />').insertBefore('#myInput');
$('#myInput').detach().attr('type', 'textarea').insertAfter(marker);
marker.remove();
```

Does nothing using 'textarea' , but works for just 'text'.Adding:

```
.val('HERE')
```

To the :

```
$('#myInput').detach().attr('type', 'textarea').val('HERE').insertAfter(marker);
```

line does result in the value of the the text box changing , so the selector is working and the `<span>` element is being inserted and removed correctly.

Is this an insurmountable security issue? Or is there a way of doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because a `textarea` is a completely different element to `input` it's easier to simply create a new `textarea` and remove the `input`. Try this:

```
$input = $("#myHiddenInput")
$textarea = $("<textarea></textarea>").attr({
    id: $input.prop('id'),
    name: $input.prop('name'),
    value: $input.val()
});
$input.after($textarea).remove();
```

Comment: For the record, the way you've passed id and name to the new textarea won't work. It should be `id: input.attr("id")` and `name: input.attr("name")`.

Answer (score 1):

You can always remove the element you want to change and add a new one...

Answer (score 1):

The problem you face is that TextArea is a an element not an attribute.

You should look to remove the previous element and replace with a new text area of the same name:

```
 var myoldInput = $('#myInput');  
 var value = myoldInput.val();
 $("<textarea id='myInput'></textarea>").before(myoldInput).val(value);
 myoldInput.remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("<textarea>value</textarea").insertAfter($(parent).find('#excerpt'));
$(parent).find('input#excerpt').remove()
```