# how to change an input element to textarea using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following html:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" style="xxxx" size="40"/>
    <input type="text" style="xxxx" size="100"/>
    <input type="text" style="xxxx" size="100"/>
    <input type="text" style="xxxx" size="40"/>
</div>
```

Now I want to change each input whose size is '100' to a textarea which has the same style as the input.

I have tried this:

```
$("input[size=100]").each(function(){
  //how to replace it?
});
```

Any ideas?

---

I used this solution found in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9112502/306719):

```
$("input[size=100]").each(function() {
    var style = $(this).attr('style'), textbox = $(document.createElement('textarea')).attr({
        id : $(this).id,
        name : $(this).name,
        value : $(this).val(),
        style : $(this).attr("style"),
        "class" : $(this).attr("class"),
        rows : 6
    }).width($(this).width());
    $(this).replaceWith(textbox);
});
```

Comment: This is trivial to Google.

Comment: I tried, it does not work. BTW, I do not think my post deserved a down-vote.

Comment: Google does not work? It does for me. The first hit I get is e.g. [jQuery change hidden input type to textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9112409) - if you have specific problems with *that*, you should add them to the question

Comment: https://www.google.com.hk/#newwindow=1&safe=strict&q=jquery+input+to+textarea&oq=jquery+input+to+textarea&gs_l=serp.3..0i30j0i8i30l8.83718.87111.7.87599.16.12.2.0.0.1.465.1837.0j1j2j2j1.6.0...0.0...1c.1.17.serp._-a9uI8YFMs&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.&bvm=bv.47883778,d.dGI&fp=a68c7ad54c7fa6a3&biw=1920&bih=986 . This is what I got.

Comment: Also, I find this `$('code').contents().unwrap().wrap('<pre/>');` But it does not work for input element.

Comment: I linked to a question above whose accepted answer should work.

Comment: `.contents().unwrap()` does not work because `input` elements don't have any children. [I know where you have the solution from](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7093417/218196), and the question is a bit different.

Comment: @FelixKling: :) That's right. That is why I ask this question.

Comment: @hguser, the solution you found would work, but it's a bit convoluted. Why not simply use the tools jQuery has given you, as shown in two of the answers below?

Comment: I do not think this is a lazy question. I googled, I just do not find the link you post. So does this mean I am lazy? I have used the `jquery replace tag` `jquery input to textarea` as keywords to google, so I think there are two many arbitrary  people like Pekka.

Comment: @DerekHenderson: I use the answer from `Richard A`.

Comment: @hguser, you're welcome to use whichever answer you feel best. Let me point out, though, that Richard A's answer is the only one that *does not* copy the styles, which you said was necessary.

Comment: @hguser, also, as you can see from this jsperf test I created (http://jsperf.com/best-way-to-replace-preserving-style), the method of appending an element and then removing the old one is a lot slower than using jQuery's `replaceWith()` method.

Comment: @DerekHenderson: I changed to `replaceWith`.

Comment: @Pekka Now, this is the first google result, funny how that works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

jQuery has a `.replaceWith()` method you can use to replace one element with another.  So, copy your styles from the input and use this method, as follows:

```
$('input[size="100"]').each(function () {
    var style = $(this).attr('style'),
        textbox = $(document.createElement('textarea')).attr('style', style);
    $(this).replaceWith(textbox);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b6xmZ/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Try something along the lines of

```
$('input[size="100"]').each(function()
{
    var textarea = $(document.createElement('textarea'));
    textarea.text($(this).val());

    $(this).after(textarea).remove();
});
```

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/SSwhK/

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$("input").each(function(){
      if($(this).attr('size') == "100") {
             my_style = $(this).attr('style');
             $(this).replaceWith("<textarea style='"+my_style+"'></textarea>");
      }
});
```

Comment: You misunderstand me, I just do not know how to replace it.

Comment: See my edit....my ans also not worth of downvote as like your question

Comment: I agree this didn't deserve a downvote... but why answer such a lazy question in the first place, enabling the user to ask more and more of them? Just sayin'.

Comment: Yes @Pekka웃 ,but I thought that it is simple that makes him clarify

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[size=100]").each(function(){
      //how to replace it?
        $(this).after('<textarea style="xxxx"></textarea>').remove();
    });
});
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/6JH6B/