# Yii how to show hidden input field of fileUpload generated with $form->formField()

Tags: php, yii, templating

I want to show the hidden input field which is generated with the CActiveForm->fileField()

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                'id'=>'user-_profile-form',
                'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
                'htmlOptions'=>array(
                    'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'
                )
            )); ?>
// some code here

<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'file_upload'); ?>

<?php echo $form->fileField($model,'file_upload'); ?>

// some code here

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

the output looks like this

```
<label for="User_file_upload">File Upload</label>

<input id="ytUser_file_upload" type="hidden" value="" name="User[file_upload]">
<input name="User[file_upload]" id="User_file_upload" type="file">
```

and i want that the hidden field shows as a normal input field.. because the design is asking for that

would be nice if anybody has a suggestion for me

thanks in advance

EDIT:

here an image of what i need [image]

Comment: What is the reason of you need to show hidden field as normal input field? Why just use normal input field?

Comment: i need a fileupload field which still shows the input field which belongs to it.. normally with other frameworks i had problems to hide this field in other designs but in this version they want to see both.. the uploadFile button and the input

Comment: Am I correct in understanding you want to show both an input for the file path, and a button to select the file?  That's the default behavior - the hidden field generated by `activeFieldField` is so that other code can `use isset($_POST[$modelClass]) to detect if the input is submitted` ([source](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php#L1386))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this client side with javascript?

Looking at this SO post: [jQuery: Change element type from hidden to input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540851/jquery-change-element-type-from-hidden-to-input#3057767) you could modify it for your form ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LD8WA/)):

```
marker = $('<span />').insertBefore('#ytUser_file_upload');
$('#ytUser_file_upload').detach().attr('type', 'text').insertAfter(marker).focus();
marker.remove();​
```